# Program that creates larger versions of itself (quine-variant)

Tags: code-golf, quine, code-generation

You are to write a program that will output source code that is

1. Larger than the original program (character wise)
2. Will print another program larger than itself when run (i.e. the new program is also a valid answer to this challenge) indefinitely

This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins.

Comment: @Kevin, The definition is recursive. The output should be a program whose output is larger than itself, and an answer to this question. So the output's output should be larger than the output, and the output's output's output should be even larger, etc.

Comment: Damn. Wanted to do this in Brainfuck. Took me almost half an hour to figure out that it is impossible to do so. :D

Comment: (or, well, at least almost impossible. YOu CAN create a Quine in BF, so this should be possible, too, but it'S too much work to bother with it)

Comment: I think you should clarify your rules. On one hand, *any* additional code output by such a program is "obviously useless"; on the other hand, *all* additional code in the output is "useful" in that it furthers the goal of answering this challenge.

Comment: @JohannesH. A selection of Brainfuck quines can be found here: http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/bf-source/quine/

Comment: Sorry for destroying your challenge. `:^)`

Comment: Naturally, such a program should be known as a quinine.

Comment: Does a program which prints its source and a comment count? For example: (bash) `cat %0 & echo \#comment`.

Comment: @facepalm42 Quine challenge answers are forbidden from reading their own source code, which makes comments tricky to use here.

Comment: Does this "creating of new code" have to be indefinite?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen technically that makes [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21832/110681) answer invalid, as the `Q` built-in in HQ9+ reads the source code, so if the quine definition counts here, it means 83 upvotes were waste.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

## [GS2 (8636bd8e)](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/tree/8636bd8), 0 bytes

This prints a single newline, which prints two newlines, which prints three newlines, et cetera.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3PCoJAGMTP7lPMC7RmgQhRl@psBz2H7m6uSH6LfgYSPfsm2p85DcP8Zsqit94rh1WHkByHVb8JJaSoaoayRjU0MJJ4G5c6MYJpUBaKtBHiRh2uqFs8Iymj9WsHTSIwyhL2k3BMT@fZiUAVvECBG9lSi@lFunHOcMB04Qb@s0jz7JJn@LHfwv3xscuaptZ4/wY)

Comment: Isn't this technically non-competing since gs2 is newer than the challenge?

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/tree/8636bd8edd3589596aec183bd7646a146a2194c9) predates the challenge by a month and a half. I just tested it, and it works as intended.

Comment: How is this not a loophole???

Comment: @MamaFunRoll Why would it be? This isn't different from an empty Retina program printing **1**, an empty Jelly program printing **0**, or an empty Stuck program printing **Hello, World!**.

Comment: I mean I guess...

Comment: @Dennis well it is slightly different, in that the Jelly program `0` doesn't print `00`, the stuck program `Hello, World!` doesn't print `Hello, World!Hello, World!`, etc.

Comment: @Cyoce It just happens that a newline outputs another newline in GS2.

Answer (score 326):

## [H9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/H9+) : 1 char

```
9
```

That's right. One character. Outputs the lyrics to [99 bottles of beer](http://esolangs.org/wiki/99_bottles_of_beer), which is a valid program. All the extraneous data does not count, but there are plenty of `9`s in there.

The output of the outputted program is the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer 59 times.

This function gives the number of times the lyrics are outputted if you run the program `n` times (if my calculation is correct):

```
f(n) = 59n-1
```

Comment: @Victor Any programming languages that output on 0 chars?

Comment: But only if the output is itself a quine.

Comment: A 0 char program in a given language, given that it's valid, will likely output 0 characters. And since 0*x=0 for any finite value x, I can claim that my outputted program is actually 9999999999999999 times bigger than the source code.

Comment: YOu can create a langauge that ignores any input but EOF and outputs any character when reading an EOF. That'd be 0-byte length and a valid answer ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. For all(solvable) problems there exists a programming language that solves the problem in 0 chars.

Comment: @Cruncher and that isn'T even hard to prove.

Comment: I still move that we name that "Cruncher's Theorem", unless it's already been discovered.

Comment: See also: http://www.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint

Comment: Haha, but does it count if the language was [specifically designed to produce quines](http://web.archive.org/web/20090602074545/http://www.cliff.biffle.org/esoterica/hq9plus.html)?

Comment: @JasonC This language was not specifically designed to produce quines. Take a look at [H9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/H9+). The only possible quine is the program `Hello, world!`

Comment: @Quincunx Oops, I got sidetracked by HQ9+!

Comment: One interesting feature is that it will also contain `2*59^n-2` instances of "Hello, world!", due to the "h" in "the".

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: Looks like you've been beat.

Comment: Also, `Hello, world!Hello, world!` is probably a quine in H9+.

Comment: Isn't this invalid, because H9+ requires the accumulator to be incremented before each command except the first?

Answer (score 127):

## Java 7: 0 chars

Save as file `Blank.java`. If you save it as any other file, replace any instance of `Blank` with the appropriate file name.

Then, run in command line via first compiling, then running. If compiling fails, stop.

I list this as **Java 7** because it might output differently for different versions of Java.

First few outputs (outputted to stderr):

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
```

```
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
^
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                                              ^
2 errors
```

```
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
^
Blank.java:1: error:  expected
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                          ^
Blank.java:1: error:  expected
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                     ^
Blank.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                          ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Blank.java:1: error: = expected
Blank.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                               ^
Blank.java:2: error:  expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
     ^
Blank.java:2: error: ';' expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
      ^
Blank.java:2: error: = expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                      ^
Blank.java:2: error: = expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                                   ^
Blank.java:2: error:  expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                                              ^
Blank.java:3: error: = expected
^
^
Blank.java:3: error: ';' expected
^
 ^
Blank.java:4: error: illegal start of type
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
     ^
Blank.java:4: error: = expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
          ^
Blank.java:4: error: illegal start of type
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
           ^
Blank.java:4: error:  expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
            ^
Blank.java:4: error: = expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
          ^
Blank.java:4: error: illegal start of type
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
           ^
Blank.java:4: error:  expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
            ^
Blank.java:4: error: = expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
              ^
Blank.java:4: error: ';' expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
                   ^
Blank.java:4: error: = expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
                                 ^
Blank.java:4: error:  expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
                                        ^
Blank.java:4: error: = expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
                                         ^
Blank.java:4: error: ';' expected
Blank.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
                                              ^
Blank.java:5: error:  expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
     ^
Blank.java:5: error: ';' expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
      ^
Blank.java:5: error: = expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                      ^
Blank.java:5: error: = expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                                   ^
Blank.java:5: error:  expected
Error: Could not find or load main class Blank
                                              ^
Blank.java:6: error: = expected
                                              ^
                                              ^
Blank.java:6: error: ';' expected
                                              ^
                                               ^
Blank.java:7: error: reached end of file while parsing
2 errors
        ^
30 errors
```

Comment: "You are to write a program that will output **source code** that is" The output is arguably not source code. And furthermore, depending on the definition of output (whether output must come specifically from `stdout`) nothing is actually output.

Comment: @nitro2k01 I quote the same: "You are to write a program that will output **source code**". Anything is source code. But only some things are **valid** source code. Additionally, it was not specified what is considered output, so I am allowed freedom there.

Comment: One problem, it isn't getting larger. It is obviously useless, so each iteration is 0 characters, and not larger.

Comment: @PyRulez But they aren't all useless. Many characters contributes to the output of the program.

Comment: But the output is also useless. You see, I make questions exploit proof by including unclear words, so when people try to exploit, instead of admitting it, I can just exploit it myself.

Comment: @PyRulez That's right. I exploited your rules. You don't need to accept this answer. When I posted this, I knew that a controversy would follow, complete with many up and down votes. I decided that it would be worth it, though.

Comment: Except that I don't care if you exploited it. Another vague rule counts you out! Yeah! (You are going to try to exploit all my questions now, aren't you?)

Comment: @PyRulez This would be a good answer for your other question, but that was closed (and I voted to close it) :-).

Comment: +1 I had a similar idea (I was trying to do it with GCC but GCC has the difficulty of stopping after unrecoverable errors). The rules don't specify that source code must be valid. The "useless" term in the rule is also very ambiguous (see my comment on answer).

Comment: the problem with this kind of "smartass" solutions is that they severy reduce the motivation for others to think and send inspiring answers. And that is what its all about here, isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure that the program itself printed the output? Wasn't that only the compiler? The program gets never compiled and itself is not interpreted nor executed, thus it wasn't able to produce any output.

Comment: @blabla999 I disagree - people don't try these challenges because someone else does something crazy. We just challenge ourselves to do it some other way. As Mark Rosewater says, "Restrictions breed creativity"

Comment: @V-X: Easy, then: this is not a `java(1)` program, but rather a program for the `javac(1)` interpreter! :-)

Comment: @wchargin Now we need an answer for the `ld(1)` interpreter...

Answer (score 125):

## GolfScript, 9 chars

```
{.'.~'}.~
```

This code outputs:

```
{.'.~'}{.'.~'}.~
```

which outputs:

```
{.'.~'}{.'.~'}{.'.~'}.~
```

which outputs:

```
{.'.~'}{.'.~'}{.'.~'}{.'.~'}.~
```

and so on.

I believe this is the shortest answer in a "real" Turing-complete programming language so far.

#### Explanation:

Basically, the original code above is a "quine-layer": it outputs a normal quine followed by itself.

In GolfScript, any code block literal (e.g. `{foo}`), if left undisturbed on the stack, is a quine.  Thus, on its own, `{.'.~'}` simply outputs itself, just like any other code block would.

The `.~` at the end of the code takes the last code block on the stack, duplicates it, and executes the copy.  When executed, the code `.'.~'` inside the code block duplicates the topmost item on the stack (i.e. the copy of itself) and appends the string `.~`.

At the end of the program, the GolfScript interpreter stringifies and outputs everything on the stack, which, in this case, consists of one more `{.'.~'}` block than in the input, plus the string `.~`.

#### Bonus:

Adding a `]` before the first `.` (to collect all the code blocks on the stack into an array before they're duplicated) makes it grow exponentially:

```
{].'.~'}.~
```

outputs:

```
{].'.~'}{].'.~'}.~
```

which outputs:

```
{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}.~
```

which outputs:

```
{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}{].'.~'}.~
```

and so on.

Comment: `{].'.~'}.~︵ ┻━┻`

Comment: @nitro2k01 my first thoughts exactly :D

Comment: @nitro2k01: Flip back that table /(@.@)/

Comment: Sorry I don't think I get the joke about the table can someone please explain?

Comment: Is "real" in quotes because HQ9+ is not real or because GolfScript is not real, or both?

Comment: @thepiercingarrow the source code resemble [this](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/flipping-tables)

Answer (score 84):

### HQ9+, HQ9++ and similars, 2 characters

```
QQ
```

This is the output:

```
QQQQ
```

Comment: I saw this and thought "Oh no, nothing can beat this." I started trying to come up with something, then it hit me. So I posted an answer.

Comment: @Quincunx Bravo, upvoted your answer.

Comment: This program has a very fast rate of growth. At generation `n`, your program length is `n^n` where `^` is the exponent operator.

Comment: @Quincunx No, I think it's `2^2^n`, where the initial program is generation 0. The length recurses `m -> m^2`.

Comment: @Vortico Good point. Even though I said it wrong, I meant: At code-length `n`, the output becomes `n^n`. However, that is false; when the code-length is `n`, the output's length is `n^2`

Comment: It is funny though because even the first two iterations are possible contenders for this question.

Answer (score 30):

## Ruby 27

A very slightly modified version of [this](http://www.justskins.com/forums/shortest-nozero-ruby-quine-122609.html) ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474861/shortest-ruby-quine)):

```
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
3
```

The number of times that `puts`-line is printed grows exponentially.

```
$ ruby quine.rb | ruby | ruby
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
puts <<3*3,3
3

$ ruby quine.rb | ruby | ruby | ruby | ruby | ruby | ruby | ruby | wc -l
    3283
```

Comment: Answer inspired by the Kaiser Chiefs

Answer (score 30):

### Lambda Calculus - 29

A simple lambda term

```
(λu.(u u)(u u))(λu.(u u)(u u))
```

Reducing this term by one beta reduction yields

```
((λu.(u u)(u u))(λu.(u u)(u u)))((λu.(u u)(u u))(λu.(u u)(u u)))
```

And so on and so on. It's a simple variant on the classic `(λu.u u)(λu.u u)` which is a quine in lambda calculus, double self application here means we get twice the output.

Comment: I'd argue that in lambda calculus, "running" a lambda term means computing its normal form, not performing a single beta reduction. Also, a term can contain multiple redexes, therefore "reducing a single redex" is an ambiguous operation.

Comment: You're right, but since this term has no normal form it makes sense to talk about this in terms of small step reduction. Since lambda calculus lacks any inherent set evaluation, I can just define "running" it to be reducing a single redex *top level* redex with call-by-name semantics no?

Comment: Well, terms with no normal form correspond to non-terminating programs. And the problem with _top level redex_ is that a term can have two redexes, neither one being a sub-term of another. You could pick some criterion which one to reduce, but I'd say that then you're getting very far from the standard lambda calculus semantics. (Anyway I appreciate your novel idea.)

Comment: (λx.x x x)(λx.x x x) :20

Comment: (λx. x x)(λx. x x x) reduces to that in a single step

Comment: shouldn't you write `(λu.u u)(λu.(u u)(u u))` instead? it is shorter, and reduces the same.

Comment: Why not just `(λu.u u)(λu.u u u)`?

Answer (score 25):

## SH script, 9

```
cat $0 $0
```

Grows at exponential rate.

Either run as `sh whatever.sh` or set it as executable.

Windows version is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21934/16504).

Comment: At the time of me writing this comment, the Quine Wiki page says that reading from the filesystem is cheating.

Comment: @LordRatte On the other hand, the challenge wasn't to write a quine.

Answer (score 20):

## dc 11

Quite simple:

```
6579792
dfP
```

The first line is repeated once every generation:

```
$ dc growing_quine.dc
6579792
6579792
dfP

$ dc growing_quine.dc | dc | dc 
6579792
6579792
6579792
6579792
dfP
```

The last line consists of the following instructions: `d` duplicates the last value put on the stack (6579792) (so that we get one more copy each time we run it), `f` prints the whole stack (which is a bunch of that same number) and `P` prints the number (6579792) out as a byte stream, which displays as `dfP`.

Comment: This can be made a little shorter: `6579792pP`

Comment: @m90 `6579792pP` outputs my original program, which isn't a strict superset of `6579792pP`; the minuscule `p` disappears. Therefore I assume that isn't valid, unfortunately.

Comment: The requirement of the problem is only that the succesive programs be "larger", which I understood to mean having greater length, although I now see that it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 19):

## redcode (recursive solution)

This is the code of the easiest warrior writable in *redcode*, the famous Imp:

```
MOV 0, 1
```

When executed, the code writes a copy of its single instruction at the next address in memory; then executes it, etc.

Answer (score 15):

## Python 3 - 55

```
print(open(__file__).read())
f=lambda:print('f()')
f()
```

This could be made shorter by replacing __ file__ with a single character filename and saving the file as that, but I felt this answer was more in the spirit of the question. After one iteration it outputs:

```
print(open(__file__).read())
f=lambda:print('f()')
f()
f()
```

Comment: This isn't a quine. See [the definition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/quine/info).

Comment: @PetrPudlák Nor are any programs in this question. This is a quine-variant problem, not strict quining.

Comment: The lambda isn't needed if the file ends in a newline character: `print(open(__file__).read()*2)`

Comment: One that meets the new quine definitions is: `s='s=%r;print(s%%s*2);';print(s%s)`

Answer (score 7):

## Smalltalk, <strike>125 61</strike> 57

The golf version looks almost unreadable so I'll explain first (and use real identifiers).

This is a variant of the "weirdest-way-to-produce-a-stack-overflow" self modifying method.

The method prints out a hello message, and its current source (for the demonstration only). Then, the code is modified to output a longer string and installed. Finally, the new code is called recursively.

In order to protect myself from an immediate runaway, it lets the user confirm in each cycle.

compile in Object:

```
eatMe_alice
   |msg mySource|

   mySource := thisContext method source.

   '**** Hello Alice' printCR.
   '  ---- my current code is:' printCR.
   mySource printCR.
   '  ---------------' printCR.

   (UserConfirmation confirm:'Again? ') ifTrue:[
       Object compile:
            (mySource
                copyReplaceString:'Hello ','Alice'
                withString:'Hello ','Alice !').
       self eatMe_alice
   ]
```

start the show by sending "eatMe_alice" to any Object; nil will do:

`nil eatMe_alice`

A nice variant is to not call the new code recursively, but instead iteratively, by unwindig the call stack and reentering into the new method. This has the advantage of not leading to a recursion exception. To do this, replace the recursive call ("self eatMe_alice") by:

```
thisContext resend
```

Golfing:

Obviously, printing and self calling was not asked for, so the shortest (for golf) is to simply append a comment to my own source and return it. As a side effect, it also gets installed for the next call...

```
x|s|Object compile:(s:=thisContext method source,'""').^s
```

Answer (score 7):

## Evoloop, 9×9 rectangle (81 cells)

The [Evoloop cellular automaton included with Golly](https://github.com/gollygang/ruletablerepository/wiki/TheRules) supports patterns which replicate themselves in a "quine-like" way. Specifically, these patterns each contain a "program"; a pattern reproduces itself by first executing the program (which creates the "body" of the daughter), and then by copying the program into the daughter.

The above applies to the more famous "Langton's Loops" cellular automaton as well as Evoloop, but Evoloop has an interesting difference, which is that it's easy to create a pattern which grows in each successive generation.

(Much *more* interesting, in my opinion, is the fact that Evoloop is a simple cellular automaton which contains patterns which reproduce themselves and evolve in a very life-like manner! I think the only known cellular automata which do this are Evoloop and its descendants. A shortcoming of Evoloop, however, is that there is one particular "best" genome; evolution always eventually converges to this one genome.)

Now, there are two shortcomings to this submission. One is that it's not clear what the "output" of a cellular automaton is. But I think that a self-reproducing automaton is "close enough" to being a quine; it's certainly no less interesting! The other shortcoming is that these patterns don't merely create a single copy of themselves; *each* copy of the original pattern attempts to create infinitely many copies of itself, and these copies end up interacting with each other in a destructive manner. So, I think I've met the requirements of this challenge in spirit, but not in letter.

Without further ado, the pattern is:

```
022222220
270170172
212222202
202000212
272000272
212000202
202222212
271041032
022222250
```

Here's the pattern again, in a format that can be copied and pasted into Golly:

```
x = 9, y = 9, rule = Evoloop
.7B$BG.AG.AGB$BA5B.B$B.B3.BAB$BGB3.BGB$BAB3.B.B$B.5BAB$BGA.DA.CB$.6BE
!
```

Okay, but what does it look like? It looks like this:

[image: A pattern in a cellular automaton which creates increasingly large copies of itself.]

In the above animation, you can see the initial pattern create a larger daughter, which creates a larger granddaughter, then a larger great-granddaughter, and finally an even larger great-great-granddaughter which starts to construct a yet larger third-great-granddaughter. If you ran this pattern for a long time, it would keep going on like this forever (or perhaps they would eventually be overtaken by the evolved organisms, which are capable of reproducing much faster; I'm not sure).

Comment: When you run it long enough you get genomes which create *smaller* offspring, which eventually self-destruct. The 'mother' at the center stays alive.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Yup. Those were the inspiration for this answer: I saw that there were organisms that get smaller with each generation, so I figured it would probably be possible to create one that would get larger with each generation. And sure enough.

Answer (score 5):

## SH script, <strike>12</strike> <strike>8</strike> 7

Store a file with

```
sed p *
```

in its own, empty directory and run from this directory using `sh [file]` or set executable.

---

Old alternative with **8 characters**, but doesn't need its own directory. Store a file with

```
sed p $0
```

and run using `sh [file]` or set executable.

Old alternative with **12 characters**:

```
sed -i- p $0
```

This will actually output to the program file itself, but where to output was not specified. Replicates itself at an exponential rate.

Comment: You might still have chance using `ed`, didn't want to look through its man page...

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <strike>41</strike>, 40 chars

```
function f(){console.log(f+"f(f())")}f()
```

The first time you run it it outputs itself with another `;f()` at the end. Subsequent runs of the output results in each "input" source printed twice.

`alert` would be shorter than `console.log` but I don't consider multiple alert dialogs to be "the" output while it seems reasonable to call multiple lines in the console as an output.

Comment: You can save one byte with `"f(f())"` instead of `"f();f()"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 5):

## Microscript II, 6 bytes

```
"qp"qp
```

The first iteration adds an extra `qp` to the end, and each successive iteration adds an extra copy of this original program to the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 6 bytes

```
"'<S@>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19J3SbYwe7/fwA)

This one was weird. All I had to do was remove a `~` from the original quine [found by Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172877/47990).

Every additional run appends another `<` to the end, e.g.:

```
"'<S@><<<<<<<<<
```

All of which do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

## Windows .BAT, 25

```
@COPY %~nx0+%~nx0 CON>NUL
```

Grows at exponential rate.

Equivalent SH version [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21929/16504).

Answer (score 4):

**ECMAScript 6 (38 Characters)**

```
(f=_=>'(f='+f+')();(f='+f+')();')();
```

Which outputs:

```
(f=_=>'(f='+f+')();(f='+f+')();')();(f=_=>'(f='+f+')();(f='+f+')();')();
```

**Edit**

You could do (28 characters):

```
(f=_=>'(f='+f+')();'+f())();
```

However it will recurse infinitely and never return anything... but this can be solved by doing something like this (42 characters):

```
(f=_=>_?'(f='+f+')('+_+');'+f(_-1):'')(3);
```

Which will output:

```
(f=_=>_?'(f='+f+')('+_+');'+f(_-1):'')(3);(f=_=>_?'(f='+f+')('+_+');'+f(_-1):'')(2);(f=_=>_?'(f='+f+')('+_+');'+f(_-1):'')(1);
```

Comment: `+_+ =_=` +1 for emoticons

Comment: 33: `(f=_=>`(f=${f})();`.repeat(2))();`

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 66 chars

```
x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)";print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2)
```

Output (134 chars):

```
x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);
```

Result of executing the result (268 chars):

```
x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);
```

next result (536 chars):

```
x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);
```

Next result (1072 chars):

```
x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);x="print(\"x=\$(repr(x))\\n\$x;\"^2)"
print("x=$(repr(x))\n$x;"^2);
```

I hope this is according to the rules.

It produces larger output, and the output itself is valid source code that produces larger output again.

Comment: Will the output, when ran, produce a valid entry?

Comment: In the first example the output is valid code. It’s a string literal containing 5 periods.
In the second example, entering the julia prompt itself wouldn’t do anything. I just thought that just giving the repl actually a newline character by hitting enter produces a longer output than the input.

Comment: Will "....." produce a larger version of itself?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I just noticed it had to be recursive... time to correct my solution. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Essentially its a quine that makes itself larger.

Comment: I guess the code is according to the rules now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>15</s> 11 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Unrelated String*

```
S+s"So+uswg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1i7WCk4X7u0uDz9/38A)

Outputs `So+uswg"So+uswg"` then `S o+uswg"S o + u s w g"` then `S o+uswg"S   o   +   u   s   w   g"`... This is a variant of the usual quine `S+s"S+s"` but with increasing spaces between each character in the string. Currently there's a bug in the parser that prevents double spaces in the code itself, otherwise this could forgo the `u`nique stripping out spaces in the code section and could be [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1i7WAmIy9P//wcA).

Comment: Still can be 11 bytes: [`S+s"So+uswg`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1i7WCk4X7u0uDz9/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 16 Characters

`` (print `(or ,-)) ``

Granted, it's interactive-only, but being able to reference the current top-level form is probably the single best way to minimize a non-trivial program that meets the specification.

What would be really interesting is what blows up the fastest. Maybe something like

`` (print `(progn ,@(loop repeat (length -) collect -))) ``

Comment: +1 For Common Lisp. Looks to me like you can skip `\`` and `,`?

Comment: @daniero Without the quotation, it just prints the original program, never growing. At that point, you may as well omit the `or`, too: `(print -)`

Answer (score 3):

## reticular, 11 bytes, noncompeting

```
"'34'coo1o;
```

This is the standard quine framework, except an extra `1` is printed after each iteration. [Try it online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=IiczNCdjb28xbzs&input=)

First few outputs:

```
"'34'coo1o;
"'34'coo1o;1
"'34'coo1o;11
"'34'coo1o;111
```

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, 15 bytes, noncompeting

```
0"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MCJEw5AzNMOnw70iRMOQMzTDp8O9&input=)

Prints `0"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý`,
which prints `0"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý"DÐ34çý`,
etc.

Comment: Both instances of `DD` can be replaced by `Ð`.

Comment: Why noncompeting?

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 1 byte

```
'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/rv56SnoKSnoJ6mYGulrqCjUGulYKAAxP/VwVKa/wE)

The open quote gives, obviously, the open quote error:

```
|open quote
|   '
|   ^
|[-1] /home/runner/.code.tio
```

Note that, by the nature of J interpreter, **the errors are printed to STDOUT**, not STDERR.

When the above is run as code, it prints:

```
|open quote
|   |   '
|       ^
|[-2] /home/runner/.code.tio
```

Then

```
|open quote
|   |   |   '
|           ^
|[-2] /home/runner/.code.tio
```

and so on. Each time the code runs, the second line is left-padded with four bytes `|`   , fulfilling the requirement of this challenge.

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), proper quine variant, 25 bytes

```
echo,~'echo,:~(,quote)'''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/rv56SnoKSnoJ6mYGulrqCjUGulYKAAxP9TkzPyderUwZRVnYZOYWl@Saqmuro6WIvmfwA)

Outputs

```
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
```

And then it outputs itself twice, on separate lines:

```
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
```

then

```
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
echo,:~(,quote)'echo,:~(,quote)'
```

and so on.

The first output is a simple variant of [standard J quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171826/78410). The added `,:~` concatenates itself vertically, where the resulting 2D array is printed as two rows of the same string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 34 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to Jo King

```python
s='print"s=%r;exec s;"%s+s';exec s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWvaAoM69EqdhWtcg6tSI1WaHYWkm1WLtYHcr7/x8A)

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```python
exec(s:='print("exec(s:=%r);"%s+s)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVmj2MpWvaAoM69EQwnGVy3StFZSLdYu1lTX/P8fAA)

Answer (score 2):

## EcmaScript 6 (51 bytes):

```
(_=x=>'(_='+_+Array(x++).join(','+_)+')('+x+')')(2)
```

It produces a longer version of itself, which can produce a longer version of itself, which can produce a longer version of itself, etc. ...

Answer (score 2):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 9 bytes

```
(:::aSSS):^
```

Modification on the standard underload quine, which is `(:aSS):aSS`. First, I changed the second `:aSS` into `:^` since it still runs the same code (by duplicating and then running the top item of the stack, which is the stuff inside the bracket) whilst saving bytes. Then I added another `S` to make it so the program gets longer, and added two more `:`s to make it so the program it produces doesn't error.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fw8rKKjE4OFjTKu7/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
"iQ ²Ä"iQ ²Ä
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XykzUOHQpsMtMPr/fwA)

Based off the [Standard Japt quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/71932#71932)

### Explanation

For first iteration

```
"iQ ²Ä"       // Take this string.        iQ ²Ä
       iQ     // Insert a quote.          "iQ ²Ä
          ²   // Double.                  "iQ ²Ä"iQ ²Ä
           Ä  // Concatenate 1 to end     "iQ ²Ä"iQ ²Ä1
              // Implicitly output.
```

On Each iteration it will concatenate another `1` to the end of the program

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
⁾ṘȮv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R476HO2ecWFf2/z8A)

Originally written for a CMC in JHT.

```
⁾ṘȮ     "ṘȮ"
   v    evaluated with the argument
⁾ṘȮ     "ṘȮ".

 Ṙ      Print a Jelly string representation of the argument,
  Ȯ     print the argument,
        then implicitly print it again.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```
a=[show,print]
".|>$([a;a])
".|>a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P9E2ujgjv1ynoCgzrySWS0mvxk5FIzrROjFWE8xJ/P8fAA)

prints (79 bytes):

```
".|>Function[show, print, show, print]\n".|>Function[show, print, show, print]
```

then, the program is doubled each time:

```
".|>Function[show, print, show, print]\n".|>Function[show, print, show, print]
".|>Function[show, print, show, print]\n".|>Function[show, print, show, print]
```

**based on this quine:**

```
".|>[show,print]".|>[show,print]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X0mvxi66OCO/XKegKDOvJBad//8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP, 38

```
<?echo fgets(fopen(__FILE__,'r')).';';
```

It will add a semicolon at each run.

Comment: Are the semicolons useless code?

Comment: @Quincunx They are, you are right. However, what would you consider useful code?

Comment: Maybe you could put in in the `';'`. Then you'd get longer outputs.

Comment: why not `<?=fgets(fopen(__FILE__,'r')).';';`?

Comment: `;<?echo fgets(fopen(__FILE__,'r'));`

Answer (score 1):

### BATCH, 26

Place this code in any .bat file and it will continue to execute (in an infinite loop) and the file will grow as well.

```
echo echo %0 ^>^> %0 >> %0
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, `%0` is the command used to invoke the script, which may not have a `.BAT` extension. You can use `%~nx0` to get the full filename of the batch file.

Comment: @JasonC AFAIK, it doesn't need the ``.bat`` to be executed. If the filename is ``execute.bat``, you can enter either ``execute`` or ``execute.bat``. Both will work.

Comment: The file itself needs to have a `.bat` extension to execute but you can leave the extension off when you execute it (when you type a command with no extension, Windows tries `.com`, `.exe`, then `.bat` in that order). If the filename is `hello.bat`, then `>> %0` will write a file named `hello`, which isn't the original `hello.bat` (and can't be executed).

Answer (score 1):

### Batch

```
set d=time  
copy c:\>loop.bat /B loop%d%.bat  
call c:\>loop.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript - 46**

```
(function $(){console.log('('+$+'());$()')}())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PYG](https://gist.github.com/Synthetica9/9796173) (6)

```
P(Q,Q)
```

Prints it's own source code, separated by newlines. The second generation would be

```
P(Q,Q)
P(Q,Q)
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

### [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL/), 83 bytes

```
0
0
1
1
1
4
1
11
4
1
11
1
2
2
1
12
18
10
18
1
32
22
1
18
26
4
26
8
18
11
6
17
4
26
```

It first prints two lines with a zero in them, and then compares each line to line 1, if they're equal (which is the case when the file is exhausted), we print what's in cell 26. The resulting output will look the same, except with an added `33`, which doesn't do anything. Next time, another line will be added, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Help, WarDoq!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Help,_WarDoq!), 1 byte.

```
H
```

Prints `Hello, World!`.

Other characters than H are valid (and safe) source code (that print other variants of Hello World).

Comment: Also works in (variants of) HQ9+.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline in HQ9+ this wouldn't continue to grow.

Answer (score 1):

## Charcoal, non-competing, 32 bytes

```
Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´αaα´ＡＦα⁺´´ια
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z8JDW85tPLQFBMGc93uWQUQeNe6CCIPguZ0gwUSQOFAVUM25jVD5czvPbfz/HwA)

Explanation:

first, go check out [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121529/55896) on the quine challenge and its explanation.

This program is that program, but with the letter a at the end of the string variable.

```
Ａ                      α            Assign to a
 ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´αa             "α´ＡＦα⁺´´ιαa", but with ´ escape character with each
                                     character, except a
                                     these are the variable being assigned to, and the
                                     rest of the program that is not the string.

                         ´Ａ         Print Ａ to the grid. current grid: "Ａ"
                            Ｆα⁺´´ι  For each character in a, print ´ + character
                                     this results in the escaped version of the string
                                     which is the literal string that is assigned at the 
                                     start, plus a escaped. current grid state: "Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´α´a"

                                   α Print a ("α´ＡＦα⁺´´ιαa"), which is the commands after
                                     the string assignment. final grid state vvv:
                                                  "Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´α´aα´ＡＦα⁺´´ιαa"

[implicitly print the grid: "Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´α´aα´ＡＦα⁺´´ιαa", the new program]
```

This new program works in the same way, except for two things:

- the "a" is escaped (which has no effect, as "a" escaped is "a")
- there is an "a" at the end of the program. this "a" will write an extra "a" after the source is produced. thus the program grows slowly

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>116</s> <s>149</s> <s>197</s> 189 bytes

```
i;main(a){printf(a="i;main(a){printf(a=%c%s%1$c,34,a,i+2);for(i=%d;i--;)",34,a,i+2);for(i=1;i--;)printf(a="printf(a=%c%s%1$c,34,a,34),",34,a);printf(a="0;printf(a=%c%s%1$c,34,a);}",34,a);}
```

#### How it works

- `main(a){` declares the main function with an *untyped variable* `a`.
- The first `printf` prints the existing source code and a `for` loop. An integer is `printf`'d into the `for` loop. This is how the multi-quine works - each time the quine program is called, it increments `d`, making the `for` loop run more times.
- The second `printf` is inside the `for` loop and prints itself, so each time the quine program is called, there are more `printf`'s, therefore generating bigger versions of itself. Be warned that this growth is exponential, due to the `for` loop incrementation *and* the multiple `printf`s.
- The third `printf` prints the remaining source code.

Requires POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 5 bytes

```
#H}"'
```

This, I believe, is the smallest growing quine possible in Gol><>. It duplicates the #H} over and over...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X9mjVkn9/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), 20 bytes

```
($'#a_$93#"$_@("_$-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fQ0VdOTFexdJYWUkl3kFDKV5FV@//fwA)

---

#### First run

Sends a dot leftward, printing the characters `(@_$` with a literal and `'` from the ASCII value 39. The dot then turns around and interprets the path as a string, printing the rest of the line.

`(@_$'#a_$93#"$_@("_$-.`

---

#### Subsequent runs

Prints `(@_$'` again, as well as a `0`, thanks to the added `@_` from the first run. The `0` ends up on the right side of the `'` symbol, which means that all `0`s printed in a previous run carry over. The dot safely ignores the additional `0`s on its path.

`(@_$'0#a_$93#"$_@("_$-.`

`(@_$'00#a_$93#"$_@("_$-.`

`(@_$'000#a_$93#"$_@("_$-.`

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 14 bytes

```bash
cat $0&cat $0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxREHFQA1K/f8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> <s>13<sup>SBCS</sup></s> <s>11</s> <s>10<sup>SBCS</sup></s> <s>9<sup>SBCS</sup></s> 6<sup>SBCS</sup> bytes

```
`④⑩`④⑩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/4dHExY8mroRS//8DAA)

I've gone and done it now! No more ascii around here now folks. This will print:

```
`④⑩`④⑩④⑩
```

Which will print:

```
`④⑩`④⑩`④⑩`④⑩④⑩
```

Which prints:

```
`④⑩`④⑩`④⑩`④⑩`④⑩`④⑩④⑩④⑩
```

And so on.

### Answer History

#### 9 bytes

```
`::.,`⑵④⑩
```

This uses the same approach as the 10 byte answer

**Explained**

```
`::.,`⑵④⑩
`::.,`      #Push the string `::.,`
      ⑵     #Double the string
        ④⑩  #Print raw then nice without popping
```

#### 10 bytes

```
`::.,`⑵:.,
```

This prints:

```
`::.,::.,`::.,::.,
```

Which prints:

```
`::.,::.,`::.,::.,`::.,::.,`::.,::.,
```

#### 11 bytes

```
`::.,`6*:.,
```

This prints:

```
`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,
```

Which prints:

```
`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,`::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,::.,
```

And so on

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcpKTyfBTAtI/v8PAA)

#### 13 bytes

```
`::.,`!⑨*:(.,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcpKTydB8dHEFVpWGno6//8DAA)

This prints:

```
`::.,::.,`::.,::.,
```

Which prints:

```
`::.,::.,`::.,::.,`::.,::.,`::.,::.,
```

And so on.

#### 14 bytes

```
`::.,(:.,)`:.,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcpKT0cDiDUTgMT//wA)

This will create pretty much the same chain as the previous 15-byter.

#### 15 bytes

```
`::.,(::.,)`:.,
```

This prints:

```
`::.,(::.,)`::.,(::.,)
```

Which prints:

```
`::.,(::.,)`::.,(::.,)`::.,(::.,)`::.,(::.,)
```

And so on.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcpKT0cDRGgmAIn//wE)

#### 18 bytes

```
`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:.,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcrKSk9HQ9FIv0ZPRzMByP7/HwA)

This will print

```
`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)
```

Which in turn prints:

```
`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)
```

Which then prints:

```
`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)`:::.,(!2/|.,)
```

And so on.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcrKSk9HQ9FIv0ZPRzMBifP//3/d5FwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (ES6/2015)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), 12 bytes

```
a=_=>'a=_'+a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/0Tbe1k4dSKprJ/5Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI1NDU/A8A)

### with invokation, 23 bytes

```
(a=_=>'(a=_'+a+')()')()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFfI9E23tZOHUSpaydqq2tqaILwf83/AA)

Every iteration adds an underscore to the parameter name

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
ToString[10#0][]&[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQ/uKQoMy892tBA2SA2OlYtOvZ/AFCgxCHtPwA)

Returns `10 (ToString[10 #0][] & )[]`, which, when run, returns `10*10 (ToString[2 #0][] & )[]`. From there, the beginning number is multiplied by 10 at every step, which increases the length of the code by 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 1 byte

```
a
```

Add prompt at head every time, error is who cares

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 bytes

```
'rd3*9[r:r]>o<
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJ3JkMyo5W3I6cl0+bzwiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

First iteration duplicates the `:` in the middle: (it actually duplicates itself):

```
'rd3*9[r::r]>o<
```

Then since there are now 2 duplication signs it will duplicate itself twice:

```
'rd3*9[r::::r]>o<
```

etc. doubling each time.

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes (Boring version)

```
':rd3*>o<
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJzpyZDMqPm88IiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

This simply duplicates the `<` at the end:

```
':rd3*>o<<
':rd3*>o<<<
```

etc. So the functionality of the program won't be effected at all. It's basically a  comment.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 7 bytes

```
95&34_"
```

Non-competing as the language postdates the challenge. This outputs:

```
95 95 34
__"
```

which in turn outputs:

```
95 95 34
95 95 34
__"
```

and so on. After ~5 runs it looks like this:

```
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
__"__"__"__"
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
__"__"__"__"
```

Answer (score 0):

## k

### 41 bytes

```
f:{{(2*#x)#x}"f:",x,";`0:f@$f;"};`0:f@$f;
```

This program prints a copy of itself, and then doubles it. Thus it grows.

### 33 bytes

```
`0:{,//$("`0:";o;"[";x;"1];")}[1]
```

This program prints itself, but with an ever-growing number as the argument. This works in the closed-source interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 14 bytes

```
" <@o&h:2d+2..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@kYOOQr5ZhZZSibaSn9/8/AA)

Subsequent versions will have an increasing number of spaces after the `"`.

#### Explanation

```
" <@o&h:2d+2.."   Push the code points of the source code, except for the 
                  quotation marks.
<                 Send the IP back west.
"..2+d2:h&o@< "   Push the code points of the source code, except for the
                  quotation marks, in reverse.
..                Make two copies of the space. One will be the additional
                  space, one will be turned into the quotation mark.
2+                Add two, to turn 32 (space) into 34 (quote).
d                 Push the stack depth. This is about twice the number of characters
                  we want to print, because there's still the first copy of the source
                  on the stack. But it's two less than twice that number, because the
                  additional space and the quote aren't duplicated.
2:                Halve the value.
h                 Increment to account for the space and quote.
&                 Repeat the next command that many times.
o                 Print that many characters from the top of the stack.
@                 Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 99 bytes

```
i;ARa="i;ARa=%c%s%c,34,a,34,i+2);Oi=%d;i--;)",34,a,34,i+2);Oi=2;i--;)Ra="Ra=%c%s%c,34,a,34",34,a,34
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 92 bytes

```java
v->{String s="v->{String s=%c%s%1$c+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//";return s.format(s,34,s);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dY5NC4JAEIbv/YpBElbyA6nbYv8gL0GX6LCta6zpKjujEOJvtxW9dAhmDu@8A89TiUFEbadMVbxnWQtEuAhtxh2ANqRsKaSCfIkAV7LavECyW6sLGALurpNbN0iCtIQcDGQwD9F53J4x836SL3300708pNwq6q0BjMvWNoIYhsdTiAGfksT7X858JXb9s3bEDTwsRo0TZyvp/hDBJv1BUk3c9hR3riFmYslMX9fB5j/NXw)

Outputs (4 bytes larger):

```java
v->{String s="v->{String s=%c%s%1$c+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//"+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//
```

[Try first output program.](https://tio.run/##fY/NCoMwEITvfYpFKkTqD9Legn2Dein0UnpIYyyxGiW7CkV8dhvRSy@F3cPMLHyzlRhE1HbKVMV7lrVAhIvQZtwBaEPKlkIqyBcJcCWrzQsku7W6gCHgzp3cukESpCXkYCCDeYjO43aMmfejfOmjn@7lIeVWUW8NYFy2thHEMDyeQgz4lCTe/3jmK7Xrn7WjbvBhadW48myl3R8i2Ip/kFQTtz3FnUuImVgy09d1sP0wzV8)

Which outputs (2 bytes larger):

```java
v->{String s="v->{String s=%c%s%1$c+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//1"+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//1
```

[Try second output program.](https://tio.run/##hY/NCoMwEITvfYpFKkTqD9Legn2Dein0UnpIYyyxGiW7CkV8dhvRS0@F3cPMLHyzlRhE1HbKVMV7lrVAhIvQZtwBaEPKlkIqyBcJcCWrzQsku7W6gCHgzp3cukESpCXkYCCDeYjO43aMmfejfOmjn@7lIeVWUW8NYFy2thHEMDyeQgz4lCSp9yef@crt@mftuBt@WHo1rj5befeHCLbqHyTVxG1PcecSYiaWzPR1HWxfTPMX)

Which outputs (2 bytes larger):

```java
v->{String s="v->{String s=%c%s%1$c+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//11"+1;return s.format(s,34,s);}//11
```

[Try third output program.](https://tio.run/##hY/NCoMwEITvfYpFKkTqD9Legn2Dein0UnpIYyyxGiW7CkV8dhvRS0@F3cPsDsw3lRhE1HbKVMV7lrVAhIvQZtwBaEPKlkIqyBcJcCWrzQsku7W6gCHg7jq5dYMkSEvIwUAG8xCdx82MmfejfOmjn@7lIeVWUW8NYFy2thHEMDyeQgz4lCRp6v0zzHxN7vpn7ZI3gGEha1wBtibeHyLY4D9IqonbnuLOfYiZWDLT13Ww9ZjmLw)

etc. (2 bytes larger every new program)

**Explanation:**

[quine](/questions/tagged/quine)-part:

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together

Challenge part:

- Unformatted source code contains `+1` and `//` to make the output program larger and compilable.
- `+1` adds a 1 to both the unformatted and formatted program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 38 bytes

```
::3a*3+-8jrfjj2,g0_0g,"+2",,1+:3d*`#@_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/38rKOFHLWFvXIqsoLSvLSCfdIN4gXUdJ20hJR8dQ28o4RStB2SH@/38A)

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3, 54 chars**

`print((lambda s:s%s)('print((lambda s:s%%s)(%r)*2);'))`

I simply modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223285/shortest-python-quine) quine.
You can try it simply doing `python this.py | python | python ... | python` many times.

Edit: found this problem on the homepage and discovered too late that it is old.

Comment: There's no issue solving old challenges.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 132 bytes

It's not often you get to recycle [answers from other questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158447/75886).

```c
x;*s="x;*s=%c%s%c;main(i){for(i=__LINE__;i--;puts(&x));printf(s,34,s,34);}";main(i){for(i=__LINE__;i--;puts(&x));printf(s,34,s,34);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/CWqvYVglMqiarFqsmW@cmZuZpZGpWp@UXaWTaxsf7ePq5xsdbZ@rqWheUlhRrqFVoaloXFGXmlaRpFOsYm@iACE3rWiWydf7/DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 155 bytes

```hs
g=putStrLn("n=1"++show n++('-'<$[1..n]));main=(\s->putStr s>>print s>>g)$"g=putStrLn(\"n=1\"++show n++('-'<$[1..n]));main=(\\s->putStr s>>print s>>g)$"
n=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P922oLQkuKTIJ09DKc/WUElbuzgjv1whT1tbQ11X3UYl2lBPLy9WU9M6NzEzz1YjpljXDqJBodjOrqAoM68ExEjXVFFCMikGZFQMQbPwGMaVZ2v0/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

### [W](https://github.com/myu-sername/w), 15 bytes

A proper quine, except it grows very oddly.

```
pp34CS+"pp34CS+
```

Iterations (You can see that the output gets between and after the source code... ):

```
pp34CS+pp34CS+"pp34CS+
pp34CS+pp34CS+pp34CS+pp34CS+"pp34CS+pp34CS+
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';exec s%s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWvdhWtci6oCgzr0ShWFW1WMvIWt06tSI1Gcgr/v8fAA)

the next iterations are:

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
# ------------------------------------
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
# -------------------------------------
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;s='s=%r;print s%%s*2;';print s%s*2;
# ------------
...
```

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';exec(a%a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FWPdFWtci6oCgzr0QjUVU1UctI01rdOrUiNRnITdT8/x8A)

```python
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
# ------------------------------------
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
# -------------------------------------
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);a='a=%r;print(a%%a*2);';print(a%a*2);
# ------------
...
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes

```c
#define a(b)*s=#b;b
a(main(){printf("#define a(b)*s=#b;b\na(%s;)",s);})
```

Every iteration adds a semicolon after the closing brace of the main function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIVEjSVOr2FY5yTqJK1EjNzEzT0OzuqAoM68kTUMJi6KYvEQN1WJrTSWdYk3rWs3///8lp@Ukphf/1y0HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 58 bytes

```lua
f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhY3rdJsldJsVQsLijLzSjTSrNLyi3ITgQxNq6LUAg1LTU0lnDIQE6AGwQwEAA) Repeats the formatted string 9 times.
This is the result of iteration 1:

```lua
f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))f="f=%qprint(f:format(f):rep(9))"print(f:format(f):rep(9))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DipDup](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/DipDup), 12 bytes

```
[[_^!]:_:]_:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVRNj9owEL3nV8xGSCSicOslWvaCqFSpVVG3tyib9QZTrA12ZJsSpP53OjPO11IOZPzmvfnyJEfh3mVd327q1Bjr4Zds/WonrJN2Y05vSgtvrFv9lGK/i6K98AIp9gRr2MDmKCz8hS1s28ZGkb82kk105kQqokhp54WuJDwfzSUoL0dpZQT4c4QlG6hSUlTFBNyCJDDOY1gsAibJiot4YH1TziMnWSxSWEFldCX8d9Gwb5KZSr/PbBFzOysr1KMQ48wY25XelM9skmLgdqnuKKHtngxZxrl2nGyE19Ti4@wJnPDKHa6QvGrjt7U8vWJ/RZym2NiCWibSm/QXKTUkFQ13ns/T3izQ7LOmIS0Pe0jL5QzwGk5CX8dWwt09e1G9oy8ol1kAcFgH1Vr4TBCNTvlAzEZCD@FNFawcILx50wxUWD6FSghMWqaWdJdttyFfzprGPpC7GPKPqPsx8hNdRB0d/VIkkoKmE8cG5i9zcu1V8xEuA3y@gx8YbswdnDFMCzHiJSJqH@rr583PaX3dxA@1anAVD6be17hRfOwDhQhTNU@JwTXQsFajgCmTAWNfpOR8ZHdzvfK/o6KDOWhbcKg6T1TnQcX8YHZAFDVmpJKdlCMV3TSSwc@H/yvA68ETtGkf08puK6zSv8NNk8W40s2Z3qhKOAl5i1@RpP0EcZzC4zK8nYFSgDnwW5i3BYXgL8GM@8SFIkdJsLTWWIgb@m6FQxxFJ6E0FfD1ByRpOOFVai@tqDwmaW63PC9fHoqszIoy@wc)

The TIO link is the DipDup interpreter written in Haskell.

Based on [my DipDup quine: `[_:]_:`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106817/9288). `[_^!]:` converts a block `[abc]` to `[[abc]_^!]`, which is equivalent to `[abc]` but longer.

This outputs `[[_^!]:_:][_^!]:_:`. After that, `[abc]abc` becomes `[[abc]_^!][abc]_^!` in each step.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=851b3cd6ce1a756d7a0304fdacbdeee2), 61 bytes

```rust
fn main(){print!("const _:()=();{}",include_str!("main.rs"))}
```

Is it cheating to use `include_str!`? :P In any case, it just keeps adding a dummy constant, growing the program larger every time.

Comment: Sorry, but `include_str!` is cheating. Our rules for [quine] challenges are at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 33 bytes (27 if alert)

```
f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`)
```

Try it:

```js
console.log('First execution');

f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`)

f();

console.log('After prev execution');

f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())

console.log('After prev execution');

f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())
f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())

console.log('After prev execution');

f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())
f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())
f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())
f=_=>console.log(`f=${f};f(f())`);f(f())

//...
```