# Shortest Code to randomly place points and connect them

Tags: code-golf, geometry, graphical-output, random

**The Task**

This is quite a simple coding task, all your program has to do is place a point on a canvas (or your alternative in another coding language) and connect it to all the dots already placed.  Your program must take in one input, the number of dots that should be placed, and output some sort of display with the dots connected.  [Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdgyrxsrri2g6u1/CodeGolf.png)

**Requirements**

- I have to be able to run it, which means that it has to have a
  compiler/tool to run it either online, or publicly available to
  download.
- You are allowed to use any library created before this challenge was set, as long as it wasn't designed for the sole purpose of solving this.
- This is a shortest code task, which means characters.  Comments, code that changes colour (for prettiness) and libraries will be ignored.
- Your answer must be unique, don't steal other peoples code, shorten it a few characters and repost it.
- It must be able to run in less than 5 minutes, for the values of 5 and 100. It must also use a resolution of at least 200*200 and put each dot in a random location on the canvas using a non-trivial distribution.

**Current Leaderboard**

```
Flawr        - Matlab        - 22  - Confirmed
Falko        - Python 2      - 41  - Confirmed
Wyldstallyns - NetLogo       - 51  - Confirmed 
Ssdecontrol  - R             - 66  - Confirmed
9214         - Red           - 81  - Confirmed
David        - Mathematica   - 95  - Confirmed
Razetime     - Red           - 118 - Confirmed
ILoveQBasic  - QBasic        - 130 - Confirmed
Adriweb      - TI-Nspire Lua - 145 - Confirmed
Manatwork    - Bash          - 148 - Confirmed
Doorknob     - Python 2      - 158 - Confirmed
Kevin        - TCL           - 161 - Confirmed
M L          - HPPPL         - 231 - Confirmed
Manatwork    - HTML/JS       - 261 - Confirmed - Improved code of Scrblnrd3
Makando      - C#            - 278 - Confirmed
Scrblnrd3    - HTML/JS       - 281 - Confirmed
Geobits      - Java          - 282 - Confirmed
```

If I've missed you out, I'm very sorry, just add a comment to your work saying so and I'll add it as soon as I see it =)

**TL;DR**

- Input - Number of dots (int, can be hard coded)
- Output - Image of randomly placed dots, all connected to each other (graphic)
- Winner - Shortest code

Comment: Am I allowed math libraries?  What libraries exactly are you trying to avoid with requirement #2?

Comment: Is there any limitation for resolution? This is quite easy if you let me output a 1x1 image

Comment: Hm, I'll post a solution to both these in the post.  Minimum resolution of the canvas must be 200*200, no maths libraries.

Comment: The resolution thing is still somewhat problematic, as you could just use a 360x1 canvas. You could just say something like "The dimensions of the canvas must be 200x200."

Comment: Thanks doorknob, changed.  Although I specifically said 360p, which should always be 360*480 (IIRC).

Comment: When you say no "math" libraries, what about languages where the default PRNG is included in "math"? I don't want to write a generator.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's a fair point Geobits.  This is getting complicated quickly.  No using libraries that contain code for this specific task.

Comment: You might want to disallow degenerated solutions such as all points being the same point. You only mention random placement in the end, but even that is not enough to prevent such solutions as you don't specify any distribution.

Comment: @IngoBürk don't quite understand what you mean.  Do you mean like all points being on the same square?  Because they can't be, hence the minimum resolution of 200*200 and random points.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert Your question never even mentions "random" except for the title and the tl;dr. Most importantly, the requirements don't state it. Also, I could just choose a distribution that suits me to make the answer easier, so you might also want to require it to be a useful distribution. Although an answer misusing this would sort of be "cheating". But not mentioning randomness in the requirements is definitely something you should fix.

Comment: @IngoBürk Okay, I'll add randomness to requirements, what else would you recommend I do?

Comment: @PopeyGilbert You could require unform distribution, though I wouldn't count on that being the default everyhwere. I think "non-trivial" is enough of a requirement. I proposed an edit.

Comment: @IngoBürk There is a [standard definition](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1325/14215) for "random" here, just so that it doesn't have to be explicitly spelled out each time.

Comment: @Geobits I think that definition needs an update. Where does it forbid other distributions? If my language happens to use a trivial distribution, that'd be fine according to there. But yeah, I guess one could easily call it out as "cheating". The other thing (actually mention randomness as a requirement) was more important

Comment: @IngoBürk If your language uses a trivial distribution, then it would either get voted up for being clever or voted down for being "cheaty", but I don't see a problem with calling it *valid*. Off hand I don't know of any built-in generator that is so trivial as to make this easier, though. Kudos to you if you find one, IMO. But yes, I agree that mentioning randomness is important. That was already done when I commented, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Someone added something about non-trivial distribution, so this is sorted =)  Just for the future, as I can't find anything on google except P(X=x)=1 for trivial distribution.  What is it?

Comment: Looking at the Matlab answer from flawr, does that mean the input can already be stored in a variable ```n```? Don't I have to read it from stdin like ```input()``` in Python?

Comment: Hm, I should probably fix that in the topic post.  I will say that you can hard code the number directly into your code, however you must be able to change it and the program will still work.  You're allowed to do one number tests for the char result.

Comment: Since you disallow library code that directly relates to the task, and that task is essentially to draw a random network graph, isn't use of native graph-drawing functions also disallowed? This restriction is far from well defined.

Comment: @comperendinous Your very correct, however I'm not sure how to word it in a manner that is fair for all languages.  If you have any suggestions on how I can change it, please do say.  As I said this is my first code golf post, and I've made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: I think code golf is never fair for all languages. ;)

Comment: You do have a point.  Java is doomed to never be the shortest, and golf script has an advantage for non-graphical problems.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert "trivial" is a general term, but a trivial distribution, in simple words, is a distribution which is "not very interesting" or "too simple" to matter in a meaningful way. You can't really pinpoint it, but that's why it fits so well. People with a math background will generally agree on what is or isn't trivial. In a sloppy way it's a more formal way of excluding distributions which were obviously used only because they make the given problem easier (or even trivial if you only have to draw a single point).

Comment: @PopeyGilbert This is the maths languages' domain, so they're naturally going to have an advantage, as Golfscript, etc. have a more general golfing advantage. I think there are some places where you could choose to draw the line, though. Most leniently, all libraries created before you posted the question are permitted. This would prevent a simple `import answer`-type submission. You could say standard (no third-party) libraries only, which permits Mathematica, etc. Or, most strictly, you could permit only primitive drawing functions: draw points and lines, but no graph-plotting functions.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thank-you for clearing that up and comperendinous, Wow, thanks for all the suggestions for wording!

Comment: @PopeyGilbert I must say, I've never seen a new user so responsive to issues with their question and also individually test each answer and maintain a leaderboard. Good work and welcome to PPGC!

Comment: Thanks @Calvin'sHobbies!  It's great to have some moral support :).  I feel it's good to be responsive to questions, otherwise people get a feeling of uneasiness.

Comment: Obviously as you say that,  I was not there for 12 hours.  Unfortunately people have this annoying need to sleep.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Matlab (22)

```
gplot(ones(n),rand(n))
```

It is assumend that n is the number of points, and it looks like this for n=10:
[image: random graph]

`n=6`:

[image: random]

#### Explaination

`gplot` is a command for plotting graphs. The first argument is a `n x n` incidence matrix (full of ones, obviously). The second argument should be a `n x 2` matrix with the coordinates of the points, but it does not matter if the second dimension is bigger that 2, so I just generate an `n x n` matrix of random values (which is 2 characters shorter than generating an `n x 2` matrix).

### Links to documentation

- [gplot](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html)
- [ones](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/ones.html)
- [rand](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)

Comment: Never used Matlab, so it will take a moment to test - But from the image it looks okay!  Congrats on doing it in 22 characters. EDIT - Turns out I can't test this, however looking at the image it seems correct so I'll allow it.  However can someone else test it please?

Comment: Thanks=) You can test it here: http://octave-online.net/ Since octave is basically the opensource version of MatLab.

Answer (score 27):

## Java : <s>318 282</s> 265

Because, ya know, Java:

```java
class M{public static void main(String[]a){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){int i=0,j,d=640,n=25,x[]=new int[n],y[]=x.clone();for(setSize(d,d);i<n;i++)for(j=0,x[i]=(int)(random()*d),y[i]=(int)(random()*d);j<i;g.drawLine(x[i],y[i],x[j],y[j++]));}}.show();}}
```

Its just a simple loop that makes random dots and draws lines between the current dot and all previous ones.

Example with 25 dots:

[image]

With line breaks and imports:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

class M{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        new Frame(){
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                int i=0,j,d=640,n=25,x[]=new int[n],y[]=x.clone();
                for(setSize(d,d);i<n;i++)
                    for(j=0,x[i]=(int)(random()*d),y[i]=(int)(random()*d);
                        j<i;
                        g.drawLine(x[i],y[i],x[j],y[j++]));
            }
        }.show();
    }
}
```

Edit: Since we're not counting imports, I imported a couple more things to save some characters later.

Edit 2: OP added an allowance for hardcoding number of dots. -17 chars :)

Comment: Nice!  Congrats on being first one.

Comment: First, but I'm sure it won't be the shortest by a long shot. Cause, ya know, Java ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem with java, the public static void main... statement uses a lot of characters.

Comment: This is verified, I've gotten it to work!

Comment: @PopeyGilbert It's worse than that. The overhead on making a frame, as you can see here, is giant. And this is about as terse as it gets.

Comment: I admire people who always solve the task in Java, even when hopeless, I'd even be too lazy to start eclipse... so +1  =)

Comment: @Chruncher Yeah, java is most definitely not the best language for code golf.  However it was the first language I learnt, and it is quite easy to pick up.  It also held me in good stead however, and is personally, my favourite language.

Comment: It's not necessary to define main's parameter as final. You can cut off those 6 characters

Comment: @Cruncher I'm using Java6 on this box (ugh), so I need the `final` to access it anonymously. I know it'll work on my other machine, but I haven't cut it yet because I'm waiting to actually test it with 8 to see if I can cut more.

Comment: +1 because I never thought I'd see Java on CodeGolf. (I still never think I'll see it as a serious contender, but, ya know, Java.)

Comment: If there is a competition that a person has won by coding in java, please link it!  It would be hilarious to see.

Comment: @KyleStrand Java competes well within its weight class. You have no idea how sad I was to see my latest edit didn't quite beat the leading HTML/JS entry, but beating C# always gives a warm feeling :D

Comment: @PopeyGilbert I think the closest you'll find is [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21900/14215), but...

Comment: You can use Char[] a instead of string[] a I think. -1 byte

Comment: Looking at this amazing golf, I gave up on Processing, since I could not come up with anything nearly as good as this, +1

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2 - <s>41</s> 35

After importing some libraries as allowed for this challenge

```
from pylab import rand as r
from pylab import plot as p
from itertools import product as x
from itertools import chain as c
```

we can plot some number of connected points with just one line of code:

```
X=r(5,2);p(*zip(*c(*list(x(X,X)))))
```

[image]

(The screenshot was generated with 10 points.)

Comment: [Referring to a deleted comment:] I know, but here "libraries will be ignored". If not, I'd definitely implement it differently. Using those libraries does not save enough characters to justify the ```import``` statements in a normal code golf challenge.

Comment: is pylab part of standard distribution? I would imagine we can't just import anything we like. Under that metric you can implement anything in python with a single import statement.

Comment: Yes [it is](http://wiki.scipy.org/PyLab). I just did what I thought would be valid. But I'm not sure. And looking into the comments shows a huge discussion going on. As soon as this is clarified I'd be willing to adjust my code.

Comment: Although this competitions view on what libraries are allowed seems to change from day to day, PyLab should definitely be allowed.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica <s>95</s> 87

With some help from belisarius.

```
CompleteGraph[n, VertexSize -> {2, 2},
VertexCoordinates -> Table[RandomInteger[{0, 199}, 2], {n}]]
```

**n=5**

[image: 5]

---

**n=100**

Timing: 2.082654 sec

[image: 100]

Comment: This is verified, I've gotten it to work!  Does Mathematica normally count as a language though?

Comment: @PopeyGilbert Sure it does. There are [~750 answers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathematica+is%3Aanswer) in Mathematica so far.

Comment: Oh, wow, Okay!  Fair enough <3

Comment: Methinks this is shorter and satisfies the rules `CompleteGraph[100, VertexCoordinates -> RandomReal[{0, 199}, {100, 2}]]`

Comment: Thanks, You are correct. I figured I couldn't win so I thought I'd make it pretty (VertexSize->{2,2}.  I did, however, overlook the fact that `100` was unnecessary to include, and that `Input[]` was optional.

Comment: I believe this code is shorter and satisfies the rules:
    `Graphics@Line@Tuples[{RandomReal[],RandomReal[]}~Table~{i, 1, n},{2}]`

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 158

Import statements not included in character count, as noted in question ("libraries will be ignored").

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
from random import randint

s=[(randint(0,200),randint(0,200))for _ in range(int(input()))]
i=Image.new('RGB',(200,200))
[ImageDraw.Draw(i).line((p,q),255)for p in s for q in s]
i.show()
```

Sample outputs:

n=2 (...):

[image: n=2]

n=10 (looks like fancy 3d thing or something):

[image: n=10]

n=100 (looks like someone went BLELEEEAARARGHHH with a red pen):

[image: n=100]

n=500, 1000, 10000 (runs in about 1.5 seconds, 5-6 seconds, and 3.5 minutes respectively):

[image][image][image]

Note: the 10000 points one was run with a slightly optimized version that changed line 3 (not including imports) to this:

```
d=ImageDraw.Draw
for p in s:
  for q in s:d.line((p,q),255)
```

Otherwise it would have taken forever. :P

Ungolfed:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from random import randint
point_count = int(input())
image_size = 200
points = [(randint(0, image_size), randint(0, image_size)) for _ in range(point_count)]
image = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for start_point in points:
    for end_point in points:
        draw.line((start_point, end_point), 255)
image.show()
```

Comment: Congrats on currently being the shortest entrant!  Love your comment on n=100.  Might be best to put image.new and image_size to 800.  Might look less weird =)

Comment: @PopeyGilbert So I *can* remove the import statements from mine? I assumed "ignore libraries" meant the library itself wasn't counted (as usual).

Comment: Yeah, because some languages have very few base functions, and have to import all their stuff.  If you think  this is not fair Geobits, then please say =)  I want to try to make this fair.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert I just asked because it's not the norm and wanted to clear it up before I chopped a few more characters from my code :D

Comment: Ah, okay, but yeah!  You can take out the library import statements.

Comment: This is verified, I've gotten it to work!

Comment: Since the resolution only has to be *at least* 200x200, you could save a few characters (5, I think) by setting `x=255` and using it to replace the instances of `200` and `255`.

Comment: Save at least another 12 characters by importing `randint as r`, `Image as I`, `ImageDraw.Draw as D`, which, as part of the imports, doesn't count to your score.

Comment: Nice tips on how to golf a persons code!  Nice to see coders helping each other out to save characters!

Answer (score 5):

### R, 66

This one is borderline cheating but I still think it's within the rules. Set up by loading the `igraph` package with `library(igraph)`, which can be downloaded from CRAN with `install.packages("igraph")`. Then assign the input to variable `N`. As per the rules, these are not counted in the total.

```
G=graph.adjacency(matrix(1,N,N),"un")
plot(G,layout=layout.random)
```

#### N = 50

[image]

Note that this code also draws self-connections. Eliminating them (although there's no rule against them) adds 6 characters:

```
G=graph.adjacency(matrix(1,N,N),"un",diag=F)
plot(G,layout=layout.random)
```

### R, 141

This is an honest-to-goodness solution in base R:

```
p=replicate(2,runif(N))
g=as.matrix(expand.grid(1:N,1:N))
plot.new()
apply(g,1,function(i) segments(p[i[1],1],p[i[1],2],p[i[2],1],p[i[2],2]))
```

although you still have to enter `N` by hand.

#### N = 50

[image]

I'm wondering if a `for` loop would be fewer characters than `apply` but I'm happy with what I've got.

Comment: I'll accept self-connects, technically the question is draw a line to ALL points.  I've tested it and confirmed it also.

Comment: Do you mind arrows connecting the points? That'll save another 5 by eliminating `,"un"` at the end of the first line.

Comment: If you don't mind, I think we should keep it so it has to be lines connecting each of the points.  That way the answer will appear similar in each of the answers.

Answer (score 5):

## QBasic or QuickBasic, 130 characters

```
SCREEN 1:RANDOMIZE:N=10:DIM X(100),Y(100):FOR I=1 TO N:X(I)=RND*320:Y(I)=RND*200:FOR J=1 TO I:LINE(X(I),Y(I))-(X(J),Y(J)):NEXT J,I
```

#### Code variations

- If you do not want to be prompted for a seed, replace `RANDOMIZE` with `RANDOMIZE TIMER`.
- If you want to be prompted for N, replace `N=10` with `INPUT N` or `INPUT "N";N`.

#### Sample runs

For `N=5`, tested with QBasic 1.1 running on DOSBox 0.74:

[image]

For `N=100`, tested with QBasic 1.1 running on DOSBox 0.74:

[image]

Comment: Oh, wow, nice image for N=5!  Love that it's a pentagram when the seed is 42.  Tested and confirmed.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + ImageMagick: 148 characters

```bash
c=()
while((i++<$1)); do
p=$[RANDOM%200],$[RANDOM%200]
c+=($p)
for e in ${c[@]};do
d+="line $p $e"
done
done
convert -size 200x200 xc: -draw "$d" x:
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ time ./line.sh 5

real    0m5.256s
user    0m0.137s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Sample output:

[image: 5 connected points]

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ time ./line.sh 25

real    0m3.043s
user    0m0.574s
sys     0m0.023s
```

Sample output:

[image: 25 connected points]

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ time ./line.sh 100

real    0m5.662s
user    0m11.156s
sys     0m0.076s
```

Sample output:

[image: 100 connected points]

Comment: Tested and confirmed.  Well done manatwork!

Comment: I'm very sorry, did I completely forget to add this to the leader boards?  I will do that now.

Answer (score 4):

### [TI-Nspire] Lua - <s>145</s> <s>135</s> 130

(Updated fixed version)

[image: Screenshot with n=10]

"Importing" math.random as "r", first, as allowed : `r=math.random`

Actual code :

```
function on.paint(g)t={}for b=1,2*n-1,2 do t[b]=r(318)t[b+1]=r(212)for c=1,b-1,2 do g:drawLine(t[b],t[b+1],t[c],t[c+1])end end end
```

Note : This code works on the TI-Nspire calculators *(TI added Lua scripting to recent OSes of this platform, with an even-based API allowing users to graph stuff etc. for example.)*

It can also be [tried online here](http://bwns.be/jim/WEBspire/editor.html) (just erase the demo script and prepend mine with   `n=10` for example)

Comment: Time for me to learn Lua!

Comment: This seems to suffer by the same mistake as [fuandon](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26725/fuandon)'s deleted [PowerShell](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36629/4198) answer and [Vlo](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30693/vlo)'s also deleted [R](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36665/4198) answer: you connect the dots in pair, not every dot with all other dots. (Lua is so rare on this site. Please fix your code instead of deleting it.)

Comment: Oh, my bad - I'll fix that soon !

Comment: There we go, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: This has been tested and confirmed!  Well done on using Lua.

Answer (score 4):

## TCL 161 chars

Clearly not going to win, but beats several others presented here, and I think it makes good use of a highly undervalued language.

```
for {set i 0} {$i<10} {incr i} {lappend l [expr rand()*291] [expr rand()*204]}
pack [canvas .c]
foreach {x y} $l {foreach {w z} $l {.c create line $x $y $w $z}}
```

[image: Example]

The default canvas size on my system appears to be 291x204. Not sure why, but using it saves 13 characters.

Fairly fast, 400 points in < 5 seconds, 500 in ~10 s. Size and points can be scaled arbitrarily and colors and line styles can be altered, at the cost of characters of course. Un-golfed and using variables to make it clearer and easier to scale and color:

```
set n 20
set width 500
set height 500
set bg_color black
set line_color white
for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
        lappend points [expr rand() * $width] [expr rand() * $height]
}
canvas .c -width $width -height $height -background $bg_color 
pack .c
foreach {x1 y1} $points {
        foreach {x2 y2} $points {
                .c create line $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2 -fill $line_color
        }
}
```

Comment: Image seems fine, unfortunately my computer isn't working so I'll test it later.  Congratulations on using such an underappreciated language.

Comment: Just confirmed it, congratulations on a successful entry!

Comment: [129](https://tio.run/##XYyxDsIwDAX3fsUbMgBD1SIWvqXNYLkeKtzIChFNi/LtoTAy3ul0ibXWNC@Ct5KZhAmKQbJFRArT6Xy53nv/Z7qbL@i7xogfGJjCi55o2Te6kCGP2OD0GH5pHbH/qGVwFEoCnYPAZbgjW@H2Umr9AA)

Comment: [122](https://tio.run/##XYwxDoMwEAR7XrGFi5ACAaLJW8DF6XARcVgnB4FD5Lc7TkrKmZFmY8l5e64OHyFV52cIRhc1IJCfb/W9f3T2YtrBJnRtpcQLRia/0wsN20pWUsQJbxgpwx8dE84/NQwOZW4iTOkHzJlSzl8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 118 bytes

```
a: collect[loop n[keep random d: 200x200]]
view[base d draw collect[foreach p a[foreach q a[keep reduce['line p q]]]]]
```

This was fun to figure out. Thanks to [Toomas Vooglaid](https://github.com/toomasv) on Gitter and 9214 for helping with this. `n` is hardcoded.

-1 byte from Bubbler.

-2 bytes from Galen Ivanov.

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to reuse the constant 200 (or `200x200`)?

Comment: the reuse saves a byte

Comment: You can put the initizlization `d: 200x200` inside the expression for `a`:  `a: collect[loop n[keep random d: 200x200]]` for 118 bytes

Comment: didn't know that it would be globally initialized, Thanks!

Comment: Your "Try it online!" doesn't seem to work.  I get the following error: `*** Red Compiler Internal Error: Script Error : copy expected value argument of type: series port bitset 
*** Where: rejoin 
*** Near:  [mold copy/part pos 40] 

/srv/wrappers/red: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory`

Comment: Although verified locally.

Comment: It looks as if, in your screenshot, you write `n:10` to initialise the value of `n`.  However, a space seems to be required `n: 10` otherwise the code does not run.  This is on Red 0.6.4.

Comment: yes. Red requires word definitions to be separated by a space, so `n:10` without a space is recognized as a token rather than a declarations.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the tio link.

Answer (score 3):

## C# Windows forms, 268

```
static void k(int n,int s){var f=new Form{Height=s+50,Width=s+25};f.Paint+=(u,v)=>{var r=new Random();var p=new Point[n];while(n>0)p[--n]=new Point(r.Next(s),r.Next(s));foreach(var a in p)foreach(var b in p)f.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.Tan,a,b);};f.ShowDialog();}
```

**N=5**

[image: Plot using 5 points]

**N=50**

[image: Plot using N=50]

## Full code is given below

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            k(50, 200);
        }
        static void k(int n, int s)
        {
            var f = new Form {Height = s + 50, Width = s + 25};
            f.Paint += (u, v) =>
            {
                var r = new Random();
                var p = new Point[n];
                while (n > 0)
                    p[--n] = new Point(r.Next(s), r.Next(s));
                foreach (var a in p)
                    foreach (var b in p)
                        f.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.Tan, a, b);
            };
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed!  When I checked the character count, I used the full code and was surprised when it came to <700 characters... >.<.  Anyway, congratulations on making a successful entry!

Comment: Isn't there some shortcut like `Pens.Tan` instead of `new Pen(Color.Tan)`?

Comment: Changed to use Pens.Tan, saving an extra 10

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 81 bytes

```
?(draw d: 200x200 loop n: 10[foreach x append[]y: random d[repend[]['line x y]]])
```

[Try it locally in REPL](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html)

[image]

Comment: Verified locally :)

Answer (score 2):

## HTML/JS, 210, thanks to manatwork

```
<canvas id=q /><script>c=q.getContext("2d");r=Math.random;e=prompt(a=[]);for(i=0;i<e;i++){a[i]={x:r()*300,y:r()*150};for(j in a)c.beginPath()+c.moveTo(a[i].x,a[i].y)+c.lineTo(a[j].x,a[j].y)+c.stroke()}</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e866azzs/9)

Comment: This is verified, I've gotten it to work!

Comment: You can use `~~` instead of `m.floor` to save 5 bytes

Comment: Make the `canvas` tag self-closing and remove the single quotes around the `id` value: `<canvas id=q />`. (Note that you have to leave one space between the last attribute value and the self-closing `/`.) BTW, in Firefox works fine without `m.floor()` and `~~`.

Comment: 219 characters: http://jsfiddle.net/e866azzs/5/

Comment: The first time I tried manatwork's jsfiddle, I thought the alert box needed a password!  I was perplexed.  How stupid a person can be.  I believe this is sufficiently different to another persons answer to warrant another place in the leader board.  Do other people think this is different enough?

Comment: Not a big difference. Same 1 `for` to set up the array, same 2 `for`s to generate the combinations, same canvas methods to do the drawing… Wait a moment! Did I enumerated 3 `for`s? Very bad. 2 `for`s, 210 characters: http://jsfiddle.net/e866azzs/9/

Answer (score 2):

## C# WPF  <s>306</s>  296

```
partial class W:Window{public W(){InitializeComponent();int x=5,i=0,j,z=200;int[]f=new int[x],s=new int[x];var r=new Random();var X=new Grid();AddChild(X);for(;i<x;i++){f[i]=r.Next(z);s[i]=r.Next(z);for(j=i;j>=0;)X.Children.Add(newLine(){X1=s[j],Y1=f[j--],X2=s[i],Y2=f[i],Stroke=Brushes.Red});}}}
```

I would like to say that I could remove Stroke=Brushed.Red. But Sadly that means that I am painting transparent lines, and my Guess is that it wouldn't really count. :P I can also shave of a couple of bytes by just creating a grid in the XAML view. But that seemed unfair, so I stripped the XAML to become a blank canvas. (I don't count the XAML as bytes...)

```
partial class W:Window
{
    public W()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int x=5,i=0,j,z=200;
        int[]f=new int[x],s=new int[x];
        var r = new Random();
        var X = new Grid();
        AddChild(X);
        for (;i<x;i++)
        {
            f[i]=r.Next(z);
            s[i]=r.Next(z);
            for (j=i;j>=0;)
                X.Children.Add(new Line()
                {
                    X1 = s[j],
                    Y1 = f[j--],
                    X2 = s[i],
                    Y2 = f[i],
                    Stroke = Brushes.Red
                });
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="W"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
</Window>
```

## 5

[image: 5]

## 100

[image: 100]

Comment: Since it is WPF it will crash at around 3k Points for Out of Memory exception.

Comment: Tested and confirmed, well done on doing it in C# WPF!

Comment: Could be shorted a little by using `var` when declaring variables.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks! I was also able to remove "this" from "this.AddChild".

Answer (score 1):

## HPPPL, <del>231</del> 220

(HP Prime Programming Language for the HP Prime color graphing calculator)

golfed it down. 11 fewer chars by drawing all possible new lines right after every new point creation. Only two nested loops instead of the previous three.

```
export c(n) begin rect();local g,h;a:=makemat(0,n,2);for g from 1 to n do a(g,1):=ip(random(1,320));a(g,2):=ip(random(1,240));if g>1 then for h from 1 to g-1 do line_p(a(h,1),a(h,2),a(g,1),a(g,2));end;end;end;freeze;end;
```

Ungolfed (270 chars):

```
export randomnet(n)
begin
rect();
local g,h;
a:=makemat(0,n,2);
for g from 1 to n do
  a(g,1):=ip(random(1,320));
  a(g,2):=ip(random(1,240));
    if g>1 then
      for h from 1 to g-1 do
        line_p(a(h,1),a(h,2),a(g,1),a(g,2));
      end;
    end;
end;
freeze;
end;
```

examples:

c(10)

[image: connect_10_points_HPPPL]

[image: connect_10_points_HPPPL_2]

c(30)

[image: connect_30_points_HPPPL]

The HP Prime color graphing calculator has a 320x240 pixel color display.

[image]

An emulator that also works with the connectivity kit is available at the HP website or here: http://www.hp-prime.de/en/category/6-downloads

... still waiting for the hardware to arrive. Update on the execution time will follow.

Today my HP Prime arrived. Here is the execution time for n=100 on an actual calculator:

[image: average execution time]

Around 0.65 s for n=100.

The emulator is about 4 times as fast (around 0.178 s) on my Core i5 2410M laptop.

Comment: Well, I have never even heard of that programming language, but it worked on the emulator so congratulations!  I've added you to the leaderboard.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I have the hardware, I’ll check the execution time. The emulator is faster than the actual calculator. But I think the 5 minutes limit for n=100 is very generous for the calculator.

Answer (score 1):

### NetLogo, 51 bytes

```
crt 9 [create-links-with other turtles fd random 9]
```

Replace 9s with other constants or variables as needed.

[image: NetLogo output]

Comment: Added to the leaderboard!  Afraid I'm not entirely sure how to test this.  I've downloaded NetLogo and I've typed it into the observer section, then tried setting it as a pen command on a plot, neither appeared to function. If you could give me some pointers, I'd be able to confirm it =)

Comment: F'rinstance: go into the 'code' tab and wrap that line in a function that starts "to go" and stops with "end". Then you can add a button to the first that calls "go" and hit it.

Comment: Confirmed!  Beautiful solution.  It's great how if you know what a turtle is you can read the code like it's English.  Almost certainly the most readable solution yet.

Comment: Neat! Thanks! I've been on the lookout for questions like this one that NetLogo is geared toward solving. Ironically, I'm also building a pyth-ish front end to remove that nice verbosity to try and make NetLogo a real golf contender.

Comment: You probably noticed some differences in output - I snuck a "hide-turtle" in when I captured the image, and I had tweaked the scale and dimensions and wrap of the world so 9's act more like 300's.

Comment: Eh, I figured it was still an excellent answer!  Can't wait to see your Pyth NetLogo code, should hopefully be a sight to behold!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 17 chars

Imports (excluded from character count):

```
"exec('global r,p;from pylab import rand as r,plot as p')".E\
```

---

```
’p(*Œ¬(*r(,2))’.E
```

Beats all other answers. Port of [Falko's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36634). Go upvote him! Input is hard-coded before the first `,`.

```py
’...’.E  # trimmed program
     .E  # evaluate...
’...’    # "p(*zip(*r(num,2)))"...
     .E  # as Python code

====================

p(*zip(*r(num,2)))  # full program
p(               )  # display plot with lines connecting all points at coordinates in ordered pairs...
  *                 # in...
   zip(         )   # each element of...
       *            # first element of...
        r(   , )    # array of...
          num       # input...
        r(     )    # arrays each containing...
              2     # literal...
        r(     )    # random numbers from 0 to 1, half-inclusive...
   zip(         )   # paired with corresponding element in...
       *            # second element of...
        r(   , )    # array of...
          num       # input...
        r(     )    # arrays each containing...
              2     # literal...
        r(     )    # random numbers from 0 to 1, half-inclusive
```

## Character scoring abuse (actually longer), 20 characters

```
""Ç6°βƵ6BÎ.:.E
```

---

```py
"..."Ç6°βƵ6BÎ.:.E  # trimmed program
               .E  # evaluate...
     Ç             # list of charcodes of...
"..."              # literal...
        β          # converted from list of base-10 values of base...
       °           # 10 to the power of...
      6            # literal...
        β          # digits to decimal...
           B       # in base...
         Ƶ6        # 107...
             .:    # with all...
            Î      # 0...
             .:    # s replaced with...
            Î      # input

====================

p(*zip(*r(num,2)))  # full program
p(               )  # display plot with lines connecting all points at coordinates in ordered pairs...
  *                 # in...
   zip(         )   # each element of...
       *            # first element of...
        r(   , )    # array of...
          num       # input...
        r(     )    # arrays each containing...
              2     # literal...
        r(     )    # random numbers from 0 to 1, half-inclusive...
   zip(         )   # paired with corresponding element in...
       *            # second element of...
        r(   , )    # array of...
          num       # input...
        r(     )    # arrays each containing...
              2     # literal...
        r(     )    # random numbers from 0 to 1, half-inclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

## PostScript, 48 bytes

```
00000000: 8814 3292 6c7b 7261 6e64 887f 9204 7d92  ..2.l{rand....}.
00000010: 837b 7b92 6b92 1a92 1992 1a34 9252 7b92  .{{.k......4.R{.
00000020: 4e92 6392 a792 4d7d 9283 7d92 657d 92a3  N.c...M}..}.e}..
```

Number of points is in the second byte (here it is 0x14 = 20 points).

Un-tokenized version:

```ps
20                          % number of points
2 mul{rand 127 and}repeat   % random points on stack
{
    {
        moveto              % move to top point on stack
        count copy          % duplicate stack
            count 4 idiv{   % for each duplicated point
            gsave
            lineto stroke   % draw a line to it
            grestore        % (removing it from the stack)
        }repeat
    }loop
}stopped                    % stop when stack is empty
```

[image: output]

Comment: Woah!  Postscript!  That's so cool, and surprisingly short.  Got any ideas how to run it?

Comment: Sure - paste the hex dump into ```k20.txt``` and run it through ```xxd -r < k20.txt > k20.ps``` to get a binary, and then load it in a postscript viewer. For the screenshot, I used Preview.app on OS X, which converts to PDF internally. You can also use ghostscript by running ```gs k20.ps``` or  load it in ghostview (aka gs or gsview). Or you can convert manually to PDF using ```gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=k20.pdf k20.ps``` and then open ```k20.pdf``` in a PDF viewer.