# Tips for golfing in Red

Tags: code-golf, tips

As the [June 2021 Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22414/language-of-the-month-for-june-2021-red) is [Red](https://www.red-lang.org/), what are some general tips for golfing in Red language?

Please suggest tips that are at least somewhat specific to Red (e.g. "remove comments" isn't a valid tip here).

Please one tip per answer!

Answer (score 7):

### Type casting:

In Red you usually use `to <type> <spec>` or the predifined `to-<type> value` functions:

```
>> to integer! 3.14
== 3
>> to-integer 2.71
== 2
>> to char! 65
== #"A"
>> to-integer #"A"
== 65
```

`<type>` can be a datatype or an example value (a prototype). That's why we can shorten the above examples as follows:

```
>> to 1 3.14
== 3
>> to 0 2.71
== 2 
>> to sp 65   ; sp is space = #" " 
== #"A"
>> to 1 #"A"
== 65
```

Of course this can be applied to all datatypes that have literal representation:

```
>> to[]123 ; to block! 123
== [123]
>> to""[123] ; to-string [123]
== "123"
>> to 1-1-1[2 6 2021]; to-date [2 6 2021]
== 2-Jun-2021
>> to now[2 6 2021]
== 2-Jun-2021
>> to 0.0.0[255 0 0] ; to tuple! [255 0 0]
== 255.0.0
>> to sky[255 228 196] ; sky is a predifined color 164.200.255 (a tuple!)
== 255.228.196
>> to 1x1[-10 42]; to-pair [-10 42]
== -10x42
>> to#{}"string"; to-binary "string"
== #{737472696E67}
```

Comment: In the case of converting a string to an integer, you can do `do"123"`, which evaluates the string as code.

Comment: @dingledooper Yes, of course! Thank you pointing this out! Why don't  you add a separate answer that covers `do`?

Comment: Ah, fare enough, will do.

Answer (score 6):

### String conversion with `do`

`do` is Red's equivalent of an `eval` command. It evaluates code as a string. It is useful when wanting to convert a string to an integer (or any valid Red expression):

```
to-integer n  # The obvious way
to 0 n        # From @GalenIvanov's type casting tip
do n          # `do` is shortest
```

Answer (score 4):

### Flatten a list of lists:

`form` the block into a string (`form` returns a user-friendly string representation of a value), then `load` the string (`load` returns a value or block of values by reading and evaluating a source)

```
>> b: [1 [2 3] [4 [5 6] 7]]
>> form b
== "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
>> load form b
== [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

>> b: [a b [c d [e f [g]]]]
== [a b [c d [e f [g]]]]
>> form b
== "a b c d e f g"
>> load form b
== [a b c d e f g]
```

Answer (score 4):

## The many uses of `collect` and `keep`

`collect`'s help page shows the following:

```
USAGE:
     COLLECT body

DESCRIPTION: 
     Collect in a new block all the values passed to KEEP function from the body block. 
     COLLECT is a function! value.

ARGUMENTS:
     body         [block!] "Block to evaluate."

REFINEMENTS:
     /into        => Insert into a buffer instead (returns position after insert).
        collected    [series!] "The buffer series (modified)."
```

basically, `collect` takes all values passed to `keep` within its argument block and returns a series with those return values.

Effectively, it works as a way in which you can apply any block of code to a series and collect results from it.

You can use it as a map:

`collect[foreach i arr[keep i + 1]]` (increments each array element)

a filter:

`collect[foreach i arr [if i < 2 [keep i]]]` (keeps all array elements less than 2)

and much more. It finds use in any general place where you need to gather values for a code golf question. I have used it in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229240/80214) as a flatmap, for example.

Answer (score 3):

### More on type casting

Another non-universal alternative to type conversion is to use some arithmetic operation on the identity value (in the desired type) for the operation and the value to convert:

`integer!` to `float!`:

```
>> to-float 5
== 5.0
>> to 0.0 5
== 5.0
>> 0.0 + 5
== 5.0
```

`char!` to `integer!`:

```
>> to-integer #"A"
== 65
>> to 0 #"A"
== 65
>> 0 +#"A"
== 65
```

`integer!` to `pair!` (a pair with equal `x` and `y` values)

```
>> as-pair 5 5
== 5x5
>> to-pair[5 5]
== 5x5
>> as-pair 5 5
== 5x5
>> to 1x1 5
== 5x5
>> 1x1 * 5
== 5x5
```

`integer!` to `tuple!` (a tuple with all parts equal)

```
>> to-tuple[255 255 255]
== 255.255.255
>> to 0.0.0[255 255 255]
== 255.255.255
>> 0.0.0 + 255
== 255.255.255
```

`integer!` or `float!` to `percent!`:

```
>> to-percent 12
== 1200%
>> to 1% 12
== 1200%
>> 0%+ 12
== 1200%
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use `any` to provide a default value

Some functions (`find`, `select` and so on) could return `none`. The long way to structure your code around their result is to use conditionals - `if`, `either` etc.

Let's find the number of occurences of each character in the string "Tips for golfing in Red". `h` is a `map!` that wiil hold the frequencies.
The verbose way is to use `either key[true-code][false-code]` - if the `key` exists do `true-code`, otherwise do `false-code` :

```
h: #()
s: "Tips for golfing in Red"
foreach c s[h/:c: 1 + either k: h/:c[k][0]]
h 
== #(
    #"T" 1
    #"i" 3
    #"p" 1
    #"s" 1
    #" " 4
    #"f" 2
    #"o...
```

We can achieve the same result with `any` - it evaluates and returns the first truthy value. The first value in the block is the value we want to test for existence, the seconf one - the default value. So, if the key doesn'r exist, `any` will return the default value:

```
h: #()
s: "Tips for golfing in Red"
foreach c s[h/:c: 1 + any[h/:c 0]]
h
== #(
    #"T" 1
    #"i" 3
    #"p" 1
    #"s" 1
    #" " 4
    #"f" 2
    #"o...
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use `alter` instead of append/insert

Sometimes it is certain that the value we are appending to a list, is not aleady present. In such case we can use `alter` instead of `append` for 1 byte less.
`alter` appends a value if it's not found in the series, otherwise, removes it from the series.

```
>> b: [1 2 3 4 5]
== [1 2 3 4 5]
>> alter b 6
== true
>> b
== [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

### `forall` instead of `foreach`

If you reference the current value of the series only once, you can save a byte by using `forall` instead of `foreach` :

```
>> p: [3 1 4 1 5 9 2]
== [3 1 4 1 5 9 2]
>> foreach n p[prin n]
3141592
>> forall p[prin p/1]
3141592
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use some of the predefined `char!` values

```
>> ? char!
    null             #"^@"
    newline          #"^/"
    slash            #"/"
    escape           #"^["
    comma            #","
    lf               #"^/"
    cr               #"^M"
    space            #" "
    tab              #"^-"
    dot              #"."
    sp               #" "
    dbl-quote        #"^""
```

`sp` for space (`#" "` or `" "`), `lf` for newline (`#"^/"` or `"^/"`), `tab` (`#"^-"` or `"^-"`) etc. can save you a byte if enclosed in brackets or between strings:

```
either a/1 = i[1][" "]
either a/1 = i[1][sp]
```