# Find an Illegal String

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source

The challenge is to find a string of characters that **cannot** appear in *any* legal program in your programming language of choice. That includes comments, strings, or other "non-executable" parts.

### Challenge

- Your program may be specific to a particular version or implementation of your language's compiler/interpreter/runtime environment. If so, please specify the particulars.
- Only standard compiler/interpreter/runtime options are permitted. You cannot pass some weird flag to your compiler to get a specific result (e.g. passing a flag to convert warnings into errors).
- If your programming language requires a specific encoding (e.g. UTF-8), your string must also be correctly encoded (i.e. strings which fail solely due to character decoding errors are not allowed).
- Every individual character in your submission must be admissible in a legal program; that is, you can't just use a character which is always rejected.
- The compiler/interpreter/runtime must give an error when given *any* source code that contains your string as a substring. The error does not have to be the same across programs - one embedding of your string might cause a syntax error, while another might cause a runtime error.

### Scoring

- Shortest illegal string for each language wins.
- You should explain *why* your string is illegal (why it cannot appear anywhere in a legal program).
- Dispute incorrect solutions in the comments. More specifically, you should provide a link to TIO or equivalent demonstrating a legal program (i.e. one that doesn't produce any errors) that contains the proposed substring.
- Some languages (e.g. Bash, Batch, Perl) allow arbitrary binary data to be appended to a program without affecting validity (e.g. using `__DATA__` in Perl). For such languages, you may submit a solution that can appear *only* in such a trailing section. Make sure to make a note of that in your answer. (The definition of this "trailing section" is language-dependent, but generally means any text after the parser has entirely stopped reading the script).

### Example

In Python, I might submit

```
x
"""
'''
```

but this can be embedded into the larger program

```
"""
x
"""
'''
y
'''
```

so it isn't admissible.

Comment: Can a counter-example rely on input from STDIN?

Comment: Would this make a good CnR?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline: Only for languages where parsing is immediate (not performed in advance) - this is true of Bash and Batch for example. For those languages, I allow for a small exception - see the last Scoring point.

Comment: @Zacharý: I think that a counterexample is valid if any execution of the program can complete successfully (i.e. if there is *some* way to run the program such that it doesn't crash). Therefore, a string is not illegal if it can be embedded in some program that doesn't crash on some input.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline: As for CnR, I considered it during the sandbox proposal, but decided against it because legitimate solutions will receive zero robber submissions (i.e. things get boring for the robbers). But, if it turns out that a lot of submissions are faulty, I may convert the question to CnR so we can weed out non-illegal strings.

Comment: Too late now I guess, but it seems like this could have been a cops and robbers challenge. There's a lot of skill evident in the attempts to make valid programs, as well as coming up with the strings in the first place.

Comment: Does it count if the standard IDE crashes at entering the string? (truely crashes)

Comment: My condolences to the Perl attempts. :)

Comment: @Kaz Well, there are only a finite number of Unicode characters that could be doubled to close an `s@`-like quote...

Comment: I think it is impossible in Perl 6 as you can use an arbitrary number of delimiting characters for a string literal `Q{{{{{{{{{{ab｣}}｣cd}}}}}}}}}}` (`ab｣}}｣cd`), and`Q` literals don't do any sort of interpretation of their contents.

Comment: In forth this seems nearly impossible, given the ability to overwrite effectively any word/symbol. I'm sure there are probably ways to do it by redefining core system words but nothing that couldn't appear after some code that backs those words up as other words first.

Comment: @reffu Yeah, I tried to create one in Forth when the challenge was first posted. I didn't succeed.

Comment: Can we assume that the program will not be given input? I have an answer, but only errors when no input is given, but works otherwise.

Comment: As long as you note that in your answer, I think it’s fair to assume no input.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's completely impossible in non-literate Haskell, thanks to nested comments.

Comment: @dfeuer That was my conclusion too. I even looked through GHC's lexer code to see if there was a loophole, but it seems *very* diligent about allowing absolutely every byte sequence inside sufficiently nested `{- -}` brackets.

Comment: This challenge rules out Turing Machine Language.

Answer (score 72):

## [Changeling](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/shapescript), 2 bytes

That's two linefeeds. Valid Changeling must always form a perfect square of printable ASCII characters, so it cannot contain two linefeeds in a row.

The error is always a parser error and always the same:

```
This shape is unpleasant.
```

accompanied by exit code **1**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85IzEtPzcnMS///n4vr/38A)

Comment: This also works with [2Col](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/2col). [Try it online!](https://gunnerwolf.github.io/2col/index.html?code=Cgo). But the reason this breaks in 2Col is that every line needs to consist of exactly 2 characters, but the empty line breaks that.

Comment: +1 because this is automatically the winner, since 1-byte solutions are not allowed because "you can't just use a character which is always rejected."

Comment: @Cowsquack tfw I forgot about my own language

Comment: @Skidsdev tfw I re-forgot about my own language, and forgot about me forgetting about my own language

Comment: @Zacharý What about 0-byte solutions?

Comment: @PyRulez, then it wouldn't be a language that could do anything.

Comment: @Zacharý [I know just the esolang for the job!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176261/16842)

Answer (score 44):

## Java, 4 bytes

```
;\u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/OSexuFjBsZqroDQpJzNZobgksQRIleVnpijkJmbmaQSXFGXmpUfHJmpWc@nrW8eUWnPVctX@/w8A)

This is an invalid Unicode escape sequence and will cause an error in the compiler.

```
error: illegal unicode escape
```

Comment: Doesn't work - one could have a string literal like `"\\u;"`.

Comment: @feersum Fixed at the cost of one byte

Comment: Does this work for the `/*` and `//` comments?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Java preprocesses source code to alter `\uXXXX` escapes before doing _anything_ else, so yes, this will work even inside comments.za

Comment: I think this is the shortest Java answer in the history of this site still..

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Actually, there is this [0 bytes Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21900/52210) (which isn't relevant anymore in the current meta, since it outputs to STDERR instead of STDOUT). Although both are pretty amazing and clever. :)

Answer (score 42):

## [COBOL (GNU)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/), 8 bytes

```
THEGAME
```

First, a linefeed to prevent you from putting my word in a commented line.

Then, historically, COBOL programs were printed on coding sheets, the compiler relies heavily on 80-character limited lines, there are no multiline comments and the first 6 characters are comments (often used as editable line numbers), you can put almost anything there, AFAIK. I chose `THEGAM` at the beginning of the next line.

Then, the 7th symbol in any line only accepts a very restricted list of characters : Space (no effect), Asterisk (comments the rest of the line), Hyphen, Slash, there may be others, but certainly not `E`.

The error given by GnuCobol, for instance, is :

```
error: invalid indicator 'E' at column 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pys/RTc8r/f@fK8TD1d3R1/X/fwA)

Also, you just lost the game.

Comment: `Also, you just lost the game.` I almost downvoted

Answer (score 27):

## JavaScript, 7 bytes

```
;*/\u)
```

Note the leading newline.

- `\u)` is an invalid Unicode escape sequence and this is why this string is invalid
- Adding a `//` at the beginning will still not work because of the leading newline, leaving the second line uncommented
- Adding a `/*` will not uncomment the string completely because of the closing `*/` that completes it, leaving the `\u)` exposed
- As stated by @tsh, the bottom line can be turned into a regex by having a `/` after the string, so by having the `)` in front of the `\u`, we can ensure that the regex literal will always be invalid
- As stated by @asgallant, one could do `1||1(string)/` to avoid having to evaluate the regex. The semi-colon at the beginning of the second line stops that from happening by terminating the expression `1||1` before it hits the second line, thus forcing a SyntaxError with the `;*`.

#### Try it!

```js
clicky.onclick=a=>{console.clear();console.log(eval(before.value+"\n;*/\\u)"+after.value));}
```

```css
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="console.clear();">Clear console</button>
<br>
<textarea id=before placeholder="before string"></textarea>
<pre><code>
 */\u)</code></pre>
<textarea id=after placeholder="after string"></textarea>
<br>
<button id=clicky>Evaluate</button>
```

Comment: `/* */\u0045 = 3` seems valid JavaScript code.

Comment: @tsh Fixed at the cost of one byte.

Comment: `3 */\u;/` is still valid.

Comment: @tsh Fixed by changing the `;` to a `)`

Comment: It is strange that Node.js accept code `0&&3 */\u)/`, but javascript shell reject it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Add `1||1` to the beginning and `/` to the end. Evaluates to `1` , and the `1*/\u)/` is never executed, so the invalid regex doesn't come into play.

Comment: @asgallant Fixed at the cost of one byte, a semicolon at the beginning of the second line.

Comment: Interesting to note that as of ES2018 (which won't be official until the end of this year) you can just wrap the whole thing in backticks due to [this](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-template-literal-revision/). You could probably fix this though just by inserting a backtick after the `/` (not that you need to fix it). (Also, the `;` doesn't force the parsing of the bad regex, it forces a SyntaxError with the `*`.)

Comment: I believe this solution is also valid for C? All the relevant syntax is identical, although you don't need to guard against regex stuff. (It's probably a polyglot for several curly-brace languages.)

Comment: @Leushenko But this doesn't work against `#if 0` as seen here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185M03BgIvLWks/plSTSzk1LyUzjSs3MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQymxOEVJ07r2/38A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ETHproductions Fixed now

Comment: @Cowsquack yeah I misunderstood the C tokenization rules. Seems `\u` doesn't start a universal char name unless there is an actual hex-quad to follow it, so it's just a well-formed punctuator+identifier pair that can be safely escaped ([6.4p4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=76)).

Comment: @feersum But alas, there is a leading newline (before the semicolon), so that cannot work.

Comment: @Cowsquack. You can save 1 byte by reverting to the old answer. See [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=896) issue. According to the ES spec, even if you put the regex into `if(0)` block (for example) such that it "never come into play", it is still syntax error (v8 engine currently doesn't throw an error because of the bug I posted, which will be fixed soon). You can also check section "Early syntax errors and RegExp errors" section from the latest ES spec.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Which particular old answer are you referring to?

Comment: @Cowsquack. To the asnwer `*/\u)`. In the comments `asgallant` said that you can put `1||1*/\u)/` and it will be correct (because regex will never be evaluated). But, it is wrong. In my previous comment I posted documented v8 bug (you can read all comments there and you can read whole ES spec section "Early errors"). The spec says that `1||1*/\u)/` **is not** a correct code (but v8 engine (which is Chrome and Node.js) doesn't throw error). The v8 issue is documented and will be fixed soon, so you can revert to 6 bytes answer, because it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Until the bug gets fixed, or until there is an implementation that allows `*/\u)` as a valid string, I will have to stick with this version, as languages in PPCG are defined by their interpreter/implementation.

Comment: @Cowsquack. Then you should change your answer's title from `JavaScript` to `JavaScript (v8 engine only)`. The bug appears only in v8 engine and it is unconsistent with the spec. If you're looking for an interpreter which rejects `1||1*/\u)/` as a valid code, you can test it in Mozilla Firefox, ParseHub, Babel Interpreter, Opera, Safari, and every other browser except Chrome.

Comment: In newer JS versions, [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) with a template string can make this not break, because the invalid escape fails. Would be: String.raw\`code here\`

Answer (score 24):

## Python, 10 bytes (not cpython)

```
?"""?'''?
```

#### Edit:

Due to @feersum's diligence in finding obscure ways to break the Python interpreter, this answer is completely invalidated for any typical cpython environment as far as I can tell! (Python 2 and 3 for both Windows and Linux) I do still believe that these cracks will not work for Pypy on any platform (the only other Python implementation I have tested).

#### Edit 2:

In the comments @EdgyNerd has found this [crack](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1lBV0tXITk/JTMv3UohucDA2BwkwnVo@qGZhzoPTT202Leey15JScleXV3dnqs@9v9/AA) taking advantage of a non-ascii [encoding declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)! This seems to decode to `print("")`. I don't know exactly how this was found but I imagine the way to fix this sort of exploit would maybe be to try different combinations of any invalid characters where the `?`s are, and find one that doesn't behave well with any encoding.

---

Note the leading newline.
Cannot be commented out due to the newline, and no combination of triple quoted strings should work if I thought about this correctly.

@feersum in the comments seems to have completely broken any cpython program on Windows as far as I can tell by adding the 0x1A character to the beginning of a file. It seems that maybe (?) this is due to the way this character is handled by the operating system, apparently being a translated to an EOF as it passes through stdin because of some legacy DOS standard.

In a very real sense this isn't an issue with python but with the operating system. If you create a python script that reads the file and uses the builtin `compile` on it, it gives the more expected behavior of throwing a syntax error. Pypy (which probably does just this internally) also throws an error.

Comment: @isaacg hmm, I actually did think of that but https://repl.it/JaHm/0 didn't work

Comment: @isaacg Oh I didn't notice, on that site you have to click the debug tab to see that it does indeed produce an error.

Comment: @isaacg like others said, that code produces errors under the debug menu.

Comment: You're right, I don't know how to use TIO. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think this is valid, even when we remove the 1st and 3rd question marks??

Comment: @officialaimm consider `"""?'''"""`

Comment: Oh, yes. Silly me!!

Comment: I made a program with this substring that runs on my machine. However, I think it does not run on many interpreters/platforms/versions. Can you specify which version of Python interpreter and OS this answer is targeting?

Comment: @feersum I edited the answer, does your program work on any online interpreters? Even if not I'd be interested in seeing the actual code

Comment: Unless you stick a second newline in front, people can just comment this out with ``#\``.

Comment: @user2357112 see above comments, backslash continuation apparently doesn't work inside comments https://repl.it/JaHm/0

Comment: [Apparently comments always end at the end of the physical line](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#comments), so you can't line-continue them.

Comment: Python 3 on Windows 7 happens to be exactly where my crack is working. [Pastebin of base64-encoded program](https://pastebin.com/qYSyncW1)

Comment: I can crack this one as well. Simply put a 0x1A character at the beginning of the file, and all the rest of it is ignored (this actually works for Python 3 as well).

Comment: [Corrected crack](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PymxONXMREE3RcHGxkbBs9LR0cnR0dU5yyLTM9NT36syOS@gvKA8OTenNMU5PS/RPTvPOzDfW8FOoTi5KLOgRK@gkqugsiQjP88IQ8QYSeT/fwA) for Pythons 2 and 3 on Linux. I realized I forgot to insert the leading newline.

Comment: I know this is really old, but after working with some people over in the Python Discord, we found [this crack](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1lBV0tXITk/JTMv3UohucDA2BwkwnVo@qGZhzoPTT202Leey15JScleXV3dnqs@9v9/AA), although I don't know if changing the encoding can be considered cheating

Comment: @feersum  Could you explain how your crack work? What does the first line `# ␀␄␀␄` of your script do?…

Comment: I believe @feersum 's cracks fall under the exception for "places where arbitrary trailing data is allowed" and don't invalidate this answer. I don't understand EdgyNerd's crack well enough to judge its validity

Comment: Are any of these reported as bugs?

Answer (score 20):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 16 bytes

```c
 */
#else
#else
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///X0FLn0s5Nac4FUr@/w8A)

`*/` closes any `/*` comment, and the leading space makes sure we didn’t just start one.  The newline closes any `//` comment and breaks any string literal.  Then we cause an `#else without #if` or `#else after #else` error (regardless of how many `#if 0`s we might be inside).

Comment: [Cracked again.](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85P6@4RCE5I7FIS6FYwVYhSEmDS0FLn0s5Nac4FUpqKllz5SZm5mloKlQrFJSWFGsUa1or1P7/DwA)

Comment: Also since C++11 raw strings seem to work, a solution is impossible with gcc.

Comment: @feersum Huh, TIL that GCC accepts those in C code. I could specify `-std=c99`, but let’s try switching to clang.

Comment: I'm really surprised that gcc accepts C++11 raw strings. Specifying the compiler version or implementation is perfectly OK, so if it's illegal in Clang, it's fair game.

Comment: Can they close raw string again? @feersum

Comment: @l4m2 I can't parse your question (who is they, and what do you mean by again?), but note that a C++ raw string literal supports a custom delimeter:  `R"foobar(...)foobar"`, and only a right paren followed by the matching delimeter and a quote will close it.

Comment: Is there a reason you need two `#else` statements, rather than just `#elif` followed by an invalid preprocessing token?

Comment: @Bbrk24 Yes; an invalid `#elif` line can be skipped by two `#if 0` lines or one `#if 1` line.

Answer (score 20):

## Rust, 65540 bytes

```rust
`"###... a lot more #s ###‪
```

That is a backtick, quote, 65535 `#`s, and an invisible U+202A Per [this advisory](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/security/advisories/GHSA-rcv6-wg5m-24v6) there is an issue with Unicode bidirectional overrides that can cause Unicode-aware editors to misrender the code, allowing bad actors to hide malicious code in plain sight. Starting in rust 1.56.1, rustc contains mitigation for that vulnerability, preventing the use of the relevant codepoints by default anywhere in the source code. However, the `text_direction_codepoint_in_literal` lint can be set to `allow` or `warn` to let use it in string literals. String literals are tricky to break out of, mainly because raw string literals are designed to allow any valid utf8 within them.  However, take a look at rustc's lexer, and you will find something [interesting](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4961b107f204e15b26961eab0685df6be3ab03c6/compiler/rustc_lexer/src/lib.rs#L173)- no more than 65535 hashtags are permitted in delimiters. Simply adding the quote followed by the long string of hashtags is enough to break any attempts at surrounding it in strings, and the U+202A is always invalid anywhere but a string. However there is another problem- someone could use the starting quote to begin a string, and hide the nastiness that way. This is where the backtick comes into play- it is an error anywhere but a literal or a comment, thus making it truly impossible for rust to contain this code. If you're wondering if there is an easier solution that fails after the lexer you'd be disappointed- anything that passes the lexer can be thrown away by a macro, and tacking on a `#[cfg(nope)]` will make anything that parses disappear.

edit: an actually valid answer this time

Comment: This solution is incorrect. `\r` by itself is allowed in regular comments (however not doc-comments).

Comment: @KonradBorowski fixed, an update to rust made that strategy completely obsolete.

Comment: "Every individual character in your submission must be admissible in a legal program; that is, you can't just use a character which is always rejected." If this is only a single U+202A, wouldn't this violate that rule?

Comment: @Bbrk24 should be fixed- after a little digging, I figured out that if you try hard enough you can put U+202A inside your code.

Comment: I was going to say that it's possible to allow a lint with `#![allow(text_direction_codepoint_in_comment)]`, but as it happens, in Rust 1.56.1 this lint was incorrectly declared and as such the compiler is not aware of it, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90614. Due to that, this is a valid solution.

Answer (score 17):

## Ada - 2 bytes

I think this should work:

```
_
```

That's newline-underscore. Newline terminates comments and isn't allowed in a string. An underscore cannot follow whitespace; it used to be allowed only after letters and numbers, but the introduction of Unicode made things complicated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 15):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
¡¡$¡"¡
```

`¡` is an unimplemented character, meaning that if the Pyth parser ever evaluates it, it will error out with a PythParseError. The code ensures this will happen on one of the `¡`s.

There are three ways a byte can be present in a Pyth program, and not be parsed: In a string literal (`"` or `."`, which are parsed equivalently), in a Python literal (`$`) and immediately after a `\`.

This code prevents `\` from making it evaluate without error, because that only affects the immediately following byte, and the second `¡` errors.

`$` embeds the code within the `$`s into the compiled Python code directly. I make no assumptions about what might happen there.

If the program reaches this code in a `$` context, it will end at the `$`, and the `¡` just after it will make the parser error. Pyth's Python literals always end at the next `$`, regardless of what the Python code might be doing.

If the program starts in a `"` context, the `"` will make the string end, and the final `¡` will make the parser error.

Answer (score 13):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 11 bytes  (and future-proof 64-bit)

```
90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 0f 0b
```

This is `times 9 nop` / `ud2`.  It's basically a [NOP sled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide), so it still runs as 0 or more `nop`s and then [`ud2`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/UD2.html) to raise an exception, regardless of how many of the `0x90` bytes were consumed as operands to a preceding opcode.   Other single-byte instructions (like `times 9 xchg eax, ecx`) would work, too.

## x86 64-bit machine code, 10 bytes (current CPUs)

There are some 1-byte illegal instructions in 64-bit mode, until some future ISA extension repurposes them as prefixes or parts of multi-byte opcodes in 64-bit mode only, separate from their meaning in 32-bit mode.  `0x0e` is illegal in 64-bit mode on current CPUs (tested on Intel Skylake).  It's [`push cs` in 32-bit mode](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push); AMD64 [freed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938318/assembly-why-some-x86-opcodes-are-invalid-in-x64) a [bunch of opcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868293/x86-32-bit-opcodes-that-differ-in-x86-x64-or-entirely-removed) for future use but as of yet neither Intel nor AMD have added any 64-bit-only extension to use them.  But they still could, which is why this isn't future-proof; some future CPU could decode `0x0e` as an opcode or prefix.

```
0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e
```

---

**Rules interpretation for executable machine code**:

- The bytes can't be jumped over (like the "not parsed" restriction), because CPUs don't raise exceptions until they actually try to decode/execute (non-speculatively).
- Illegal means *always* raises an exception, for example an illegal-instruction exception.  (Real programs can catch that with an exception handler on bare metal, or install an OS signal handler, but I think this captures the spirit of the challenge.)

---

**It works because a shorter byte-string ending in `ud2` could appear as an imm32 and/or part of the addressing mode for another instruction, or split across a pair of instructions**.  It's easiest to think about this in terms of what you could put before the string to "consume" the bytes as part of an instruction, and leave something that won't fault.

I think an instruction can consume at most 9 bytes of arbitrary stuff: a SIB byte, a disp32, and an imm32.  i.e. the first 2 bytes of this instruction can consume 8 NOPs and a ud2, but not 9.

```
c7 84 4b 00 04 00 00 78 56 34 12        mov dword [rbx+rcx*2+0x400],0x12345678
```

Can't beat 9 nops:

```
    db 0xc7, 0x84   ; opcode + mod/rm byte: consumes 9 bytes (SIB + disp32 + imm32)
    times 9 nop          ; 1-byte xchg eax, ecx or whatever works, too
    ud2
  ----
   b:   c7 84 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90        mov    DWORD PTR [rax+rdx*4-0x6f6f6f70],0x90909090
  16:   0f 0b                   ud2
```

64-bit mode:

```
 c7 84 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e 0e        mov    DWORD PTR [rsi+rcx*1+0xe0e0e0e],0xe0e0e0e
 0e                      (bad)
```

But the bytes for 8 NOPs + ud2 (or `times 9 db 0x0e`) can appear as part of other insns:

```
    db 0xc7, 0x84   ; defender's opcode + mod/rm that consumes 9 bytes

    times 8 nop          ; attacker code
    ud2

    times 10 nop    ;; defenders's padding to be consumed by the 0b opcode (2nd half of ud2)
----
  18:   c7 84 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 0f        mov    DWORD PTR [rax+rdx*4-0x6f6f6f70],0xf909090
  23:   0b 90 90 90 90 90       or     edx,DWORD PTR [rax-0x6f6f6f70]
  29:   90                      nop
  2a:   90                      nop
  ...
```

Comment: The rules here weren't really clear enough for me to consider posting an asm/machine code answer. For example, why can't you just do `ud2`? It seems you're saying that you interpret the rules as forbidding jumping over the bytes, so `ud2` would work just fine on its own, no? Oh…I guess you're saying the issue is that `ud2` can appear as a prefix to a valid instruction? The second part of this answer was a little difficult for me to understand.

Comment: @CodyGray: Right, the 2 bytes that encode `ud2` can appear in the `imm32` of any instruction.  I was thinking about this in terms of what bytes can you put before such a string that "consume" `0f 0b` as part of an earlier instruction instead of  decoding as `ud2`.  I wasn't totally happy with how I ended up presenting it, but I wanted to illustrate why only 8 `nop`s wasn't enough, and what happened with 9 `nop`s + `ud2`.

Comment: @CodyGray: An asm source program would be a totally different answer.  That would have to error the parser used by the assembler, not produce faulting machine-code.  So something like `%else` / `%else` might work to defeat `%if 0`, which can normally protect any invalid text from being parsed.  (idea from a CPP answer)

Comment: Don't quite satisfy. Your solution may be just in .data. (though it makes it impossible)

Comment: @l4m2: To make the question answerable / interesting, I had to limit it to *code* that's executed (and not jumped over).  See the rules interpretation bullet points in my answer.  That would also rule out static data, of course.  Because then it's not machine code at all, it's just data.  This question required more adaptation than most for a machine-code answer to make sense, because there is no compile/assemble stage where you can error the parser, we're just talking about bytes already in memory.

Answer (score 11):

## Shakespeare Programming Language, 2 bytes

```
.:
```

Explanation: If this string is in the title of the play, the `.` ends it and the `:` is not a valid character name. Similar problems occur in an act and scene name. No character can speak a line beginning with `:`, and the `.` will end a `Recall` statement, which can otherwise create a comment.

Answer (score 10):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 12 bytes

```
DOTRYAGAINDO
```

[Try to crack it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FPyQo0tHd0dPPxf//fwA)

INTERCAL's approach to syntax errors is a bit special. Essentially, an invalid statement won't actually error unless the program tries to execute it. In fact, the idiomatic syntax for comments is to start them with `PLEASE NOTE`, which really just starts a statement, declares that it isn't to be executed, and then begins it with the letter `E`. If your code has `DODO` in the middle of it, you could prepend `DOABSTAINFROM(1)(1)` and tack any valid statement onto the end and you'll be fine, if it's `DODODO` you can just bend execution around it as `(1)DON'TDODODOCOMEFROM(1)`. Even though INTERCAL lacks string literal syntax for escaping them, there's no way to use syntax errors to create an illegal string, even exhausting every possible line number with `(1)DO(2)DO...(65535)DODODO`, since it seems that it's plenty possible to have duplicate line numbers with `COME FROM` working with any of them.

To make an illegal string, we actually need to use a perfectly valid statement: `TRY AGAIN`. Even if it doesn't get executed, it strictly must be the last statement in a program if it's in the program at all. 12 bytes is, to my knowledge, the shortest an illegal string can get using `TRY AGAIN`, because it needs to guarantee that there is a statement after it (executed or not) so `DOTRYAGAIN` is just normal code, and it needs to make sure that the entire statement is indeed `TRY AGAIN`, so `TRYAGAINDO` doesn't work because it can easily be turned into an ignored, normal syntax error: `DON'TRYAGAINDOGIVEUP`, or `PLEASE DO NOT TRY TO USE TRYAGAINDO NOT THAT IT WOULD WORK`. No matter what you put on either side of `DOTRYAGAINDO`, you'll error, with either `ICL993I I GAVE UP LONG AGO`, `ICL079I   PROGRAMMER IS INSUFFICIENTLY POLITE`, or `ICL099I   PROGRAMMER IS OVERLY POLITE`.

Comment: There might be a few other compile-time errors which can fire before `ICL993I I GAVE UP LONG AGO`.

Comment: If, while using every line label, you also `COME FROM` every line label, it might be a bit difficult to divert control flow around the block, but there's nothing at all stopping you from just `GIVING UP`!

Answer (score 9):

## [APL](https://www.dyalog.com/) and [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) and [Fortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 3 bytes

```
'
```

Newline, Quote, Newline always throws an error since block comments do not exist:

- APL: [`unbalanced quotes`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///n0ud6/9/AA)
- MATL: [`string literal not closed`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/n0ud6/9/AA)
- Fortran: [`Invalid character in name`](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v/nUuf6/x8A)

Comment: This applies to MATL too

Comment: I think this would work in Fortran too.

Comment: Also J I believe

Comment: @Jonah [Nope.](https://tio.run/##y/pvoGBl8J9Lneu/5n8A "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah.  Would `\n)\n'\n` work for J?

Comment: @Jonah It seems so.

Comment: What is this J code?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena wdym?

Comment: Illegal J code.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I still don't get what you're asking. Maybe we should discuss it [in chat](https://apl.chat)?

Comment: See J code in the comments above

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Ah, `\n` there stands for a line break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133068/discussion-between-fmbalbuena-and-adam).

Answer (score 9):

### Commodore 64 Basic, 2 bytes

```
B
```

(that's a newline followed by the letter "B").

Any line in a Commodore 64 program must begin with either a line number or a BASIC keyword, and stored programs only permit line numbers.  There are no keywords beginning with "B" (or "H", "J", "K", "Q", "X", "Y", or "Z").

Comment: If I append `=0` then this just becomes an assignment statement...

Comment: @Neil, that would be a valid immediate-mode command, but not a valid program.

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 16 bytes

```
*/"
#endif<#@#>
```

Works because:

- `//` comment won't work because of the new line
- `/*` comment won't work because of the `*/`
- You can't have constants in the code alone
- Adding `#if false` to the start won't work because of the `#endif`
- The `"` closes any string literal
- The `<#@#>` is a nameless directive so fails for T4 templates.
- The new line tricks it so having `/` at the start won't trick the `*/`

Each variation fails with a compilation error.

Comment: Weird that you decided to include T4 templates in your code. Isn't T4 considered a separate language?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I don't know I had never heard of them. Someone commented this didn't work when you included T4 templates so I added the fix.

Answer (score 7):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 3 bytes

```
\
```

(linefeed, backslash, linefeed)

I recently said "[Pasting in invalid-formatted text [into Desmos] simply does nothing.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220829/96155)" As I recently discovered, this isn't quite true. When pasting in multiple lines, it's happy to throw errors if one of them is invalid. Now, this works even if some of those lines other are blank, causing them to be ignored. Therefore, we make a `\` on its own line, which is guaranteed to throw an error.

Logically, we *should* be able to knock this down to two bytes (`\`, `LF`), as no legal line can end with a `\`. However, Desmos strangely interprets this as an empty list (normally represented as `[]`), for reasons I don't understand. This makes that two-byte string an unusual almost-illegal string, where the only valid program containing that string is the string itself.

Comment: "However, Desmos strangely interprets this as an empty list (normally represented as `[]`)" -- I had to test this, and it's even weirder than I thought. Desmost doesn't just *interpret* it as `[]`, but *renders* it as `[]`.

Comment: Not only does it parse `\¶` (where ¶ is newline) as an empty list, it literally parses anything in the form `[invalid expression]¶` (replace [invalid expression] with something that would normally error) as an empty list too. Try `f(n)=a¶` for example.

Answer (score 5):

## [Literate Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/literate.html), 15 bytes

Repairing a [deleted attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133563/) by nimi.

```hs
\end{code}
5
>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NydHNySxJLUosSf3/nysmNS@lOjk/JbWWy5TL7v9/AA)

nimi's original attempt is the last two lines, based on Literate Haskell not allowing `>` style literate code to be on a neighboring line to a literate comment line (`5` here). It failed because it can be embedded in a comment in the alternate ("LaTeX") literate coding style:

```hs
\begin{code}
{-
5
>
-}
\end{code}
```

However, the `\begin{code}` style of Literate Haskell does *not* nest, neither in itself nor in `{- -}` multiline comments, so by putting a line with `\end{code}` just before the line with the `5`, that workaround fails, and I don't see a different one.

Answer (score 4):

## Free Pascal, 18 bytes

```
*)}{$else}{$else}
```

First close all possible comments, then handle conditional compile.

Please comment here if I forgot something.

Comment: @user902383 Does your example contain the leading newline of his snippet?

Comment: @BrianJ  nope, i thought it was just formatting issue, my bad

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Free Pascal. Just put them after `begin end.`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 but it seems that codes after the `end.` become valid is allowed by the question.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
"e#"
:"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/XylVWYnLSun/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Hack](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack/releases/tag/v1.0) (a variation of [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

Thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) for pointing out that Brain-Hack doesn't support comments, saving me a byte.

```
(}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/n0uj9v9/AA)

Comment: How do you do comments in Brain-Flak? I don't know of any way to do those.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `#` [TIO](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/n0tZo/b/fwA)

Comment: Huh undocumented behavior.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I always assumed they were documented somewhere. I'll look at adding them.

Comment: You don't need the newline in BrainHack or Craneflak, Rain-Flak is the only one of the three versions that has line comments.  Although Craneflak parses on the fly so its impossible to solve this in Craneflak, any solution could be beaten by prepending `(()){()}`.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```javascript
`*/
\u`~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/QUufK6Y0oe7/fwA)

I think this should be illegal enough.

### Previous JS attempts in other answers

> ```
> ;*/\u)
> ```
>
> By @Cows quack
>
> As an ES5 answer this should be valid, but in ES6 wrapping the code with a pair of backticks wrecks this. As a result valid ES6 answers must involve backticks.
>
> ```
> `
> `*/}'"`\u!
> ```
>
> By @iovoid
>
> This is an improved version involving backticks. However a single `/` after the code breaks this (It becomes a template literal being multiplied by a regex, useless but syntactically valid.) @Neil made a suggestion that changing `!` to `)`. This should theoretically work because adding `/` at the end no longer works (due to malformed regex.)

### Explanation

```javascript
`*/
\u`~
```

[This is by itself illegal, and also blocks all single and double quotes because those quotes cannot span across lines without a `\` at the end of a line](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/QUufK6Y0oe7/fwA)

```javascript
//`*/
\u`~
```

and

```javascript
/*`*/
\u`~
```

[Blocks comments by introducing](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fXz9BS58rpjSh7v9/AA)
[illegal escape sequences](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fXytBS58rpjSh7v9/AA)

```javascript
``*/
\u`~
```

[Blocks initial backtick by introducing non-terminated RegExp literal](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/IUFLnyumNKHu/38A)

```javascript
console.log`*/
\u`~
```

[Blocks tagged template literals by introducing an expected operator between two backticks](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nPz1BS58rpjSh7v9/AA)

Comment: "Template literal... multiplied by a regex." Only in JavaScript would that be a legal expression.

Answer (score 4):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 6 bytes

````go
*/```
````

[Try to crack it online!](https://tio.run/##S8///59LSz8hIeH/fwA)

The grave accent (`) marks a raw string literal, inside which all characters except `, including newlines and backslashes, are interpreted literally as part of the string. Three `'s in a row are the core: adjacent string literals are invalid and ` always closes a ` string, so there's no way to make sense of them. I had to use 3 more bytes for anti-circumvention, a newline so we can't be inside a single-line comment or a normal quoted string, and a */ so we can't be inside a multi-line comment.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>3</s> 4 bytes

```
»»
€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7kO7uR41rfn/HwA)

Alternative 4 bytes:

```
»

€
```

*+1 byte because [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a) found an issue with the old approach*

Jelly has no comments, and every line in the code is parsed whether or not it is reachable. The only way to prevent some code from being executed is by putting it in a string literal. There are different types of string literals based on the ending character, but almost all start with `“`. This is countered by `»`, which terminates a string (and interprets it as a dictionary-compressed string).

The only two string literal types that do not terminate at the first `»` are `⁾` and `⁽`, which each process precisely the next two characters. However this still leaves the newline unescaped.

Thus `€` (each/map) will always be executed on a link (line) of its own. It tries to get a link from its left; since none exists, the interpreter errors.

Comment: [Nope](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R475Du7keNa35/x8A)

Comment: @emanresuA fixed

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, Excel; 3 bytes

For a single-cell Formula (starts with `+` or `=`). Otherwise, you can just put whatever arbitrary text you want into a cell.

Here it is: `1"1`

- A string has to be enclosed in `"`s. A double quote must be escaped by `""`.
- The `"` has to be a string token boundary.
- If it's the end, following a string with a 1 is illegal.
- If it's the beginning, preceding a string with a 1 is also illegal.

Answer (score 4):

### Swift,  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

There's control characters in here, so I'll just give their ASCII values: `0A 22 00`.

Most of the ways that other C-family languages do this don't work in Swift, because Swift allows nested block comments.

The null character always generates at least a warning. However, if it's in the middle of whitespace or a line comment, it's *only* a warning, not an error. Additionally, Xcode lets you put most control characters inside of a block comment and just rolls with it.

Emphasis on most. For some reason, if you have a null byte in the middle of a block comment or string literal, the Swift compiler gets lost and can't find the end, no matter where it is. This causes an error (and also breaks Xcode's syntax highlighting).
So, this is three bytes:

- `0A` -- a newline, to make sure we're not in a line comment or single-line string literal.
- `22` -- `"`, the start of a single-line string literal, unless it's inside a multi-line string literal or block comment. This does not end a multi-line string literal if it started inside of one.
- `00` -- a null byte, to prevent the block comment or string literal from terminating.

The original answer used `/*` (open block comment) rather than `"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 4 bytes

```
/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@fi0uf6/9/AA)

Since `AWK` doesn't have a method to do multi-line comments, need 2 newlines before and 1 after `/` to prevent commenting out or turning this into a regex, e.g. add `1/`. The most common message being `unexpected newline or end of string.

[With previous crack](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fP4aLS5/r//9ELiAEAA)

Comment: I enjoyed this.

Comment: Thanks. I enjoyed coming up with it :)

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 2 Bytes

A linefeed followed by an underscore - the `_` functions as the line continuation character in VBA, and as there is nothing in the line directly to the left or above the line continuation, coupled with VBA's lack of multiline comments means that this will always throw the compile time error `Compile Error:` `Invalid character`

```vba
_
```

Comment: You do depend on your pattern starting on a new line... so, add a newline.

Comment: @Deduplicator it already has a new line, - it does not matter what follows the `_`, only that there is no valid line to the left or above it

Comment: What if it is embedded like this: `myfunction(` `\n_` `)`?

Comment: @Deduplicator the line continuation character must be on the same line as it is continuing ie `Public Function Foo( ByVal bar as Integer, _ ` (new line) `bas as long) as double` - so yes, it would result in an error if you called the function you described

Comment: Ok, in that case it's more like `myfunction( _` `\n_` `)`. Sorry for the confusion. To put it another way, you should have used two newlines.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am not sue what you mean. There is no way to escape a newline (or any character) in VBA so it should not be necessary to add a newline before, and appending literally anything to the end of this VBA code will cause the `illegal character` error - eg `\n_"test"`, `\n_12321` ,  `\n_#if`,  `\n__` and `\n_\n` will all result in the the error as will all of the above with any prepended code

Comment: so, `myfunction(_` (newline) `_` (newline) `)` would be an error?

Comment: Yes, that would cause an error. example test code `function myfunction(  _\n_` (slightly changed from your example as you cannot have a `_` directly following a `(` or any other character  - I believe that this is why this works in VBA) - of note is that `function myfunction(  _\n _...` would be valid (note the added space)

Comment: In VBA, every string is illegal and results in an error...

Comment: @MegaMan I am not sure what you mean ... I'll just take that as a joke

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 11 characters

```
`
`*/}'"`\u)
```

The backticks make sure to kill template strings, the quotes get rid of strings, the newline avoid commented lines, the end of comment avoids block comments, and the last backtick and escape (with a `)` to avoid appending numbers or `/`) try to start a invalid string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/gStBS79WXSkhplTz/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, 2 bytes

```
!
```

Nothing continues past the end of a line, so all you need is a line break followed by something which can't be the start of a statement. `!` is the logical not operator, but you aren't allowed to ignore the result of an expression, so even something like `!10` would be invalid (while `X=!10` works, of course)

Similar things will work in any language where everything ends at the end of a line, as long as it parses the code before executing it.

There are a lot of alternative characters that could be used here, so I think it would be more interesting to list the ones that COULD be valid.

`@` is the start of a label, for example, `@DATA`; `(` could be part of an expression like `(X)=1` which is allowed for some reason; any letter or `_` could be a variable name `X=1`, function call `LOCATE 10,2`, or keyword `WHILE 1`; `'` is a comment; and `?` is short for `PRINT`.

Comment: oh, for some reason when I edited the post it was duplicated...

Answer (score 3):

### TI-Basic (83+/84+/SE, 24500 bytes)

```
A
```

(24500 times)

TI(-83+/84+/SE)-Basic does syntax checking only on statements that it reaches, so even 5000 `End` statements in a row can be skipped with a `Return`. This, in contrast, cannot fit into the RAM of a TI-83+/84+/SE, so no program can contain this string. Being a bit conservative with the character count here.

The original TI-83 has 27000 bytes of RAM, so you'll need 27500 `A`s in that case.

### TI-Basic (89/Ti/92+/V200, 3 bytes)

```
"
```

Newline, quote, newline. The newline closes any comments (and disallows embedding the illegal character in a string, since AFAIK multiline string constants are not allowed), the other newline disallows closing the string, and the quote gives a syntax error.

You can get to 2 bytes with

```
±
```

without the newline, but I'm not sure whether this counts because `±` is valid only in string constants.

Comment: Done, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rockstar](https://github.com/dylanbeattie/rockstar), <s>4</s> 5 bytes

*Crossed out 4 is still 4 :(*

```
)
"""
```

Rockstar is a very... wordy language.
While `"` can be used to define a string, such as `Put "Hello" into myVar`, to my knowledge there is no way for 3 quotes to appear outside of a comment, and the close paren ensures that won't happen either (Comments in Rockstar are enclosed in parentheses, like this).

Rockstar also has a poetic literal syntax, in which punctuation is ignored, so the newline makes sure that the 3 quotes are the start of a line of code, which should always be invalid

Comment: What about `(()""")`, wouldn't that be a no-op?

Comment: @BMO first paren opens a comment, 2nd paren does nothing because it's commented, 3rd paren closes the comment, then you have `""")` being parsed as code, which is invalid

Comment: Hmm, nested comments are not in the specs. Comments seem to be discouraged anyways. But you oversaw *poetic string literals* which allow any string, so [`Goethe says )"""` is valid](https://rockstar.connorwfitzgerald.com/jSbTeCCtb6o).

Comment: @BMO good point, can be fixed by inserting a newline inbetween `)` and `"""`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>58</s> <s>23</s> 27 bytes AND proof of impossibility at bottom

This snippet is valid in any Ruby version prior to Ruby 2.3 (when [heredocs](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1675-using-heredoc-for-prettier-ruby-code) were added):

```
=end
)}end/;[}'"\//;[}#{]}
```

Old version (invalid):

```
=end
)}end/;kill(Process.pid,-9)'"\//;kill Process.pid,-9
```

This cannot be used anywhere in a Ruby program except after `__END__`.

## Proof of impossibility

This solution is impossible in any Ruby version after and including Ruby 2.3.

Any Ruby solution can be inserted into this snippet and function as a valid program:

```
<<'string'

# Insert code here

string
```

With this particular snippet, you can add (note leading newline)

```
string
```

to your solution in order to invalidate the program. However, changing the "name" of the heredoc will again invalidate your solution. Heredocs can have infinite placeholders, meaning a solution accounting for all of them would be infinitely long. Thus an answer in Ruby 2.3+ is impossible.

Thanks to histocrat for pointing this out.

Comment: Invalid, _cannot_ appear. Needing a kill command means it can be put in a program that still runs

Comment: Can kill be redefined to not work properly?  For example define kill to do nothing with the input?

Comment: @ASCII-only--yes, that's true. I thought that the question was to raise an error, not disallow a valid program. Sorry about that. Will remove.

Comment: Not quite--If you put single quotes around the heredoc terminator like [so](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/38ZG3cM1yFWdyzY1L4VLsxZI6ltH16orxeiDaOXq2FoukAKugtKSYg2lkMTibIW0xMyc1BSF4tLk5NTi4rTSnJxKJc3//wE "Ruby – Try It Online"), it won't interpolate with `#{`. I don't think this is solvable in Ruby due to this feature.

Comment: @histocrat I was wondering how long it would take for someone to notice! Congrats, I guess.

Comment: Invalid answers need to be deleted.

Comment: [Proof of impossibility is still a valid answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16172/76162). Though I think the proof might need to be a little more strict

Comment: Updated solution to reflect impossibility in Ruby 2.3+.
@JoKing The proof depends on allowing infinitely long answers or not. I'm too lazy to check atm whether infinitely long answers are allowed; but if they are, then I can add one to this answer

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 7 bytes

```
 */
#`#
```

- Adding a `//` at the beginning will still not work because of the leading newline, leaving the second line uncommented.
- Adding a `/*` will not uncomment the string completely because of the closing `*/` that completes it, leaving the `#` exposed.
- Adding `` ` `` will not quote the string completely, because of `` ` `` that completes a string, leaving the `#` exposed.
- Regular expressions won't work because of `#` following `/` character.
- `/` following `*` cannot be parsed as a regular expression, as regular expressions cannot have newlines

#### Try it!

```js
clicky.onclick=a=>{console.clear();console.log(eval(before.value+" */\n#`#"+after.value));}
```

```css
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="console.clear();">Clear console</button>
<br>
<textarea id=before placeholder="before string"></textarea>
<pre><code> */
#`#</code></pre>
<textarea id=after placeholder="after string"></textarea>
<br>
<button id=clicky>Evaluate</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch (1.x, except 1.2 beta), scratchblocks syntax, 26 bytes

```
when gf clicked
say(()/()
```

Leading new line ensures that "when gf clicked" will not be in a comment, so that what's below it will run.

This errors when run in the Stage, because the Stage cannot use the `say` block.

This errors when run in a sprite by itself, because a divide by zero is attempted. (When a number argument is blank, it is read as 0.)

This errors when run in a sprite when `)` or a new line is added after it, because it doesn't change what the existing code does.

This errors when run in a sprite when something else is added after it, because it creates an undefined block which causes an error when run.

---

1.2 beta is excluded because it featured comment blocks (different from modern comments), which supported multiline, which this could be put into.

Versions past 1.4, including the Experimental Viewer, are excluded because dividing by zero does not cause an error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), 2 bytes.

```
))
```

### How it works

- `(` to the nearest `)` is a comment.
- But nothing can match the second `)` above in this syntax.
- Thus it is syntax error.

Comment: What about `(())`? Does Dis not support parentheses inside comments?

Comment: @mayube *Comments may be used, enclosed in parentheses. They can't be nested.*

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip Classic](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/releases/tag/v0.18), 10 bytes

```
;\"
;`
*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@fyzpGics6gUvL@v9/AA)

I *think* this should be solid, but I welcome anyone to prove me wrong.

#### How?

A semicolon at the start of a line begins a single-line comment, so our code is effectively

```
*;
```

and Pip complains because `*` is a binary operator and needs a left operand.

If we add any expression before the snippet, we still get an error because `*` needs a right operand. No operand can be supplied because `*` is followed by the expression terminator `;`.

We can't wrap the snippet in a string, because every possible string delimiter (`"`, `\"`, and `` ` ``) is matched by a delimiter in the snippet. (In a regular `"`-delimited string, the backslash is not an escape character, so it doesn't mess anything up.)

Finally, we can't comment out the last line of the snippet because Pip Classic doesn't have block comments.

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 7 bytes

Technically, knight programs aren't allowed to contain anything outside of `\r`, `\n` ,`\t`, or `<space>`-`~`, so you could just submit `<NUL>` for a one byte solution.

Additionally, each knight program is exactly a single expression; handling things after that experssion is up to the implementation. So, you could prefix any program with `TRUE`—a valid expression—after which anythign afterwards would be undefined behaviour. However, that kind of defeats the spirit of the question as well IMO, so let's assume that we're actually in some arbitrary expression:

```
#"'#'
$
```

The idea is since `$` is not a legal function, it cannot appear outside of strings.

- If there's no leading code, then the comment removes the rest of the first line.
- If we're embedded in a comment, our entire first line will be commented out, leaivng a lone `$`, which is illegal.
- If we're inside a `"` string, then the first `"` will close it, which is then followed by the legal `'#'` string
- If we're inside a `'` string, then the first `'` will close it, with the remaining `'` being commented out by the `#`, leaving `$` by itself.

Comment: Each character needs to be admissible on it's own according to the challenge rules so the the 1 byte solutions are not admissible anyway

Answer (score 2):

## Fortran, 14 bytes

```
end program
e
```

No multiline comments or preprocessor directives in Fortran.

Comment: Is there a good way to test this online? Also, which version/compiler of Fortran?

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>10</s> <s>8</s> <s>12</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> <s>14</s> 16 bytes

<sup>-2 byte thanks to Mazzy finding a better way to break it</sup>
<sup>+4 -1 bytes thanks to IsItGreyOrGray</sup>

```
$#>
'@';
"@";
@=
```

I hope this works. `'` and `"` to guard against quotes, `#>` to break the block-comment, new lines to stop the single-line comment, both `'@` and `"@` to catch another style of strings, and then starts an improper array to throw a syntax error.

The logic being they can't use either set of quotes to get in, they can't block-comment it out, If `@"` is used, it'll create a here-string which can't have a token afterwards, and if they leave it alone, it'll try to make a broken array. This statement wants to live so hard, I keep finding even more holes in the armor.

Comment: Smart! What about this ` '"#>\n@{=` : protectors + `@{=`

Comment: Or protectors + `@=`

Comment: Cool! It may also be worth looking in the direction `LFCR` (reverse of `CRLF`), `EOF` and other control chars.

Comment: Embedding in $( ') makes it legal
$(
#>
'@
"@"
@=
')

Comment: @IsItGreyOrGray AAAAAAAAAAAw heck.

Comment: It looks like changing #> to $#> will break it as "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..." It might be made legal again somehow, but I don't have a way. Yet. :)

Comment: Sorry... Embed between write-host ' and '@

Comment: @IsItGreyOrGray Sonofagun. Now featuring semi-colon armor?

Comment: Nice! I've got nothing. Everything I've tried has failed.

Answer (score 2):

## Scratch (scratchblocks2), 3 bytes

There's no such thing as an error in scratchblocks2 - just red-colored blocks - but this can't be expressed in actual Scratch, so I think it's OK.

```
<?
```

Leading newline to avoid this just being commented or ::ed out.

Then a predicate block with it's label starting with `?` - there's no such block.

Comment: Can't test it (I'm not going to install scratchblocks2), but I don't see why `say [\n<?]` breaks. The `[]` seem to support parsing `\n` (like for [*drop-down menus*](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Block_Plugin/scratchblocks2#Advanced_Syntax)).

Comment: There's a leading newline.

Comment: I think `define\n<?` defines the `<?>` block as a custom block, [here](https://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch2&script=define%0A%3C%3F)

Answer (score 2):

## PCRE Regex, <s>6</s> 7 bytes

```
\E
)](+
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QKHgbr/3)

Any string not containing `\E` would be legal inside a `\Q`...`\E` literal sequence. By starting this one with `\E`, we break out of such a sequence if we were in one. And if we weren't in one, but are preceded by a `\`, then it will be treated as a literal `\E`, and we'll still be guaranteed not to be inside a `\Q`...`\E`.

`(+` is not part of any legal group structure, and will generate a compile-time error ("Incomplete group structure" and/or "The preceding token is not quantifiable" / "quantifier does not follow a repeatable item") anywhere other than:

1. Within a `\Q`...`\E`. We've handled this. We can't be inside one thanks to the `\E`.
2. Immediately after a `\`. But since we have it immediately after a `\E`, it can't be immediately after a `\`. Note that `\E` alone is valid, even if there was no `\Q` before it.
3. Inside a `#...` style comment. This can only happen in free-spacing mode, but this can be turned on by `(?x)` anywhere in a regex, so we need to handle it.
4. Inside a `(?#...)` style comment.
5. Inside a character class, e.g. `[(+]` or `[\Q\E(+]` – or even `[\Q\E](+]`, which will be treated as `[](+]`, which, since an empty character class is not part of PCRE syntax <sub><sup>(except in PCRE2 with the PCRE2_ALLOW_EMPTY_CLASS option enabled)</sup></sub>, is treated as a character class consisting of `](+` (the beginning of a character class is the only place where `]` does not need to be escaped).

Because of #3, we need a newline, to break out of any `#...` comment we may be in.

Because of #4, we need a `)`, to break out of any `(?#...)` comment we may be in.

And it is because of #5 that we need to put `]` in front of the `(+`. This closes any character class we might have been in. If we hadn't already put a newline and/or a `)` to close a potential comment, we'd need this to be `]]`, because a character class can't be empty and `]` is allowed to be the first character in a class without being escaped. In any case, thanks to having a character before our `]`, it even works if a range was started, e.g. `[!-\E)](+`.

*Edit: Silly me, didn't protect it from being inside comments. Fixed.*

Answer (score 2):

## ECMAScript Regex, 4 bytes

```
]](+
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/u4WI1X/1)

This is a quite a bit easier [than PCRE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179130/17216). There's no `\Q`...`\E`, no free-spacing mode, and no comments. But if we used just `](+` we could still be inside a character class and have our `]` escaped, as `[\](+]` which would be treated as a character class of `](+`. So we still need the double `]` to make sure we exit any character class we may have been in, which works even if a range was started, e.g. `[!-]](+`.

`(+` is illegal in any context other than a character class, and will give an error message such as "Nothing to repeat" or "Incomplete group structure" / "The preceding token is not quantifiable".

Answer (score 2):

## Runic Enchantments, 3 bytes

```
Ṷ
```

One of many possible variations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/0zFrr//8B)

Runic utilizes unicode combining characters in a "`M` modifies the behavior of `C`" (where `C` is a command). As such, no two modifiers are allowed to modify the same command and the parser will throw an error if such an occurrence is found.

Similarly, certain commands that redirect the IP cannot be modified in any way, due to the existence of direction modifying modifier characters (and both in the same cell makes no sense).

There is no way to escape or literal-ize the string to make it valid. Tio link contains a `;` in order to bypass the higher-priority "no terminator" error.

Answer (score 2):

### [NDBall](https://esolangs.org/wiki/NDBall) 2 bytes

specificly in [NDBallSim V1.0.1](https://github.com/aspwil/NDBallSim/releases/tag/v1.0.1)

```
##
```

a hashtag is a memory cell instructor and requires a direction, two of them anywhere will cause the error

```
NDBall Parse ERROR @ LINE (whatever line): Memory cell requires a direction ex: #>12
```

this double character trick can actually be done with many more chars, to be exact all of these `)(,}{|><+-pP$%Y][E` and newline

This is actually all (discounting digits) of the useable chars in the lang itself because it never has a case where you use the same char twice

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 6 bytes

```cs
"*/#
```

---

`#` is only used in C# to specify a preprocessor directive. Preprocessor directives are only valid if the `#` is the first non-whitespace character on its line. As a result, it doesn't even matter if the specified directive exists or not (so the shortest solution is to not specify any directive name).

The only way to prevent `#` being interpreted as a directive is to put it in a comment or string.

It is not possible to comment out `#` because `//` is prevented by preceeding newline and `/*` is prevented by `*/`. It is not possible to enclose it in a string because multiline strings must start with `@"`, but there is no way to put `@` in front of a string that would capture `#` (`@\n"` is not valid).

Answer (score 2):

## [Grass](https://github.com/TryItOnline/grass), 3 bytes

```
wWv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy9KLC7@/788vOz/fwA)

Grass programs are written using only `w`, `W`, and `v`; all other characters are ignored.

`w` is necessary because any characters placed before the program's first `w` are ignored.

`W` is expected to be followed by a sequence of `w` characters to form a function application; however, it is instead followed by a `v`, which causes a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 4 bytes

Silos is competitive \o/

```
x+
```

S.I.L.O.S runs on a two pass interpreter / compiler. Before execution a "compiler" attempts to simplify the source into an array describing the sourc Each line is treated separately. x+a is an assignment operator that will add ea to the value of x and store it into x. However the "compiler" will break. Therefore, we take this string and add a new line before and after ensuring it's on its own line and breaks the compiler.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/5@rQpvr/38A)

Comment: Why doesn't `ax+` error out?

Comment: undefined compiler behavior @EriktheOutgolfer

Answer (score 1):

### [AutoHotkey](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/AutoHotkey.htm), 5 bytes

` is the escape character. You can only escape a " when assigning it to a variable.

\n*/ prevents it from being commented out or assigned to a variable.

```
*/`"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk)<sup>1</sup>, 3 bytes

```
◊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/n@vR9C6u//8B)

#### Explanation

The newlines force `◊` to be [parsed](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/blob/0806b9db5681ee9ba1eea9f90bfe86a8e35d8fe0/Parser.hs#L192) as a supposed built-in, however since it's not (yet) [implemented](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/blob/0806b9db5681ee9ba1eea9f90bfe86a8e35d8fe0/Builtins.hs#L47) the parsing fails with `unexpected "\9674"` or an error because of empty lines.

**Note:** Initially I tried to force an inference failure, but the type-checking is done lazily and [one can easily "un-break" programs with adding a valid main function](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbFKXKqsQcLk/P//8B).

---

<sub>1: The code might work at some point in the future. So to be precise any version of Husk as of before the date of this post (ie. at least up to [commit 0806b9d](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/commit/0806b9db5681ee9ba1eea9f90bfe86a8e35d8fe0)).</sub>

Comment: An inference failure would have been fun, but this is probably shorter than that would be anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <del>3</del> 4 bytes

Fixed a for loop bug noted by @Jono2906

```
)ø.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@fS/PwDr3//wE)

### Explanation

```
\n    Terminate a line-comment
)     End a for loop
 ø    Clear the stack
  .   Try to print the TOS item, which will create an error to the program.
```

Comment: [3 bytes using strings](https://tio.run/##y05N//@fK4Hr/38A "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: But [this](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fgyuBS/P/fwA) is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable), 2 bytes

```
''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X139/38A)

All Unreadable commands must be of the form `'""…"`, with one `'`  followed by 1 to 10 `"`s. Having two successive `'`s anywhere in the program leads to `error: parser failed: invalid command (0): '`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lean Mean Bean Machine](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/lmbm), 8 bytes

```
OO
0/
&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8lNyv3/39@fy0CfS@3/fwA)

Begins with a leading newline.

Unfortunately this is basically an entire invalid program, but it can be inserted into larger programs, and there's no way to my knowledge to prevent the runtime error.

LMBM creates a 'marble' (aka instruction pointer) at every `O` in the code, and there is no way to prevent this (which now that I think about it causes some issues if you need an `O` in a string). `&` is the division operator in LMBM.

In short, this snippet causes a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` runtime error.

Comment: Needs a leading newline, otherwise you can just add some dummy leading characters so that the marbles dont land in the division by zero

Comment: @thejonymyster good catch!

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/CSkmJS8laSbvi/38A)

Comment: This can be [commented out](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/CytA6RilGXen/fwA "Add++ – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mayube Fixed. Thx.

Comment: Add++ doesn't seem to support multi-line strings or comments so [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/59L6f9/AA "Add++ – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mayube Nope [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/CSkmJi0tJSbvi/38A "Add++ – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Chicken, 2 bytes

```
ih
```

Thanks to jimmy23013

Comment: Can you make comments in Chicken?

Comment: @BgilMidol Nope

Comment: *Every individual character in your submission must be admissible in a legal program; that is, you can't just use a character which is always rejected.* So maybe `ih` is better.

Comment: @jimmy23013 okay

Answer (score 1):

## PowerPC for XBox 360, 19 bytes

```
~
J,e~
J,e~
J,e~
J,
```

The operative sequence is `~␊J,`, in which the linefeed may be replaced with any byte less than 32 and the J with any byte congruent to 2 mod 8.

If this sequence appears on a four-byte boundary (which it will, in the above  string) on an executable page, it codes an `xdcbt` (prefetch to L1 cache, skipping L2); any (even speculative) jump to it will then break cache coherency, probably leading to a crash soon after. Since the branch predictor even predicts computed jump destinations, this will happen sooner or later, see [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2018/01/07/finding-a-cpu-design-bug-in-the-xbox-360/).

I wish I had been able to force an all-printable version, but LF is pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
ɬĹ
```

Just one amongst many.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5JojO///BwA)

It's pretty simple, actually:
Pyt has no comment markers, so every valid character when using Pyt's proprietary encoding (not UTF-8) does something.

ɬ pushes the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Ĺ returns the least common multiple of the top two elements on the stack
You can replace ɬ with either ɫ or ʊ (only the lowercase and uppercase letters, respectively), and you can replace Ĺ with the vast majority of the functions in Pyt, as most of them only work on numbers.

There is another 2-byte family of solutions:

```
do
```

where d is any digit (0-9), and o is either ҏ or Ƒ.
ҏ palindromizes a string or array and does not work on numbers, and Ƒ flattens the array at the top of the stack, but errors if the top of the stack isn't an array.

And there is a singleton (not in a family of solutions):

```
ɔŕ
```

ɔ clears the stack, and then ŕ pops the top of the stack (and errors out if it is empty).

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <del>12 bytes</del> 25 bytes

Tried to cut all strings. Not really short.

```
.
"'/%+)}]>#
=pod
=cut
.
```

- First newline to exit comments (there are no multiline comments)
- then `.` in first column to exit format sections
- end strings (there are strings like `"..."`, `'...'` and like `qw/.../` but instead of '/' other chars can be used
- start a POD section (`=pod` at the beginning of the line)
- end the POD section (`=cut` at the beginning of the line)
- `.` is not in any comment and is invalid.

After `__DATA__` or `__END__` there is no code. There starts a data section.

Hope this is correct (my first step on code golf ...)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kILUoZ8GCpaUlaboWN9VzKxVUKhRsFZS4uGwL8lO4bJNLS7j0uJSsuQqKMvNKFJQyUnNy8pUgyqG6YLoB

Comment: @pxeger Thanks! I have to exit all types of strings first...

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Also, this challenge is impossible in Perl due to [`__END__`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kILUoZ8GCpaUlaboWN5ULijLzShSUMlJzcvKVrLni4139XOLjubhsC_JTuGyTS0u49CBKoTpgOgE)

Comment: @emanresuA - I don't think so, because all after `__END__` or `__DATA__` isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
#“
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/n0v5UcOc//8B)

Each line in Gaia is a separate function, so the newline ensures that the code starts at the beginning of a function. Even putting a newline in a string literal will start a new function, since Gaia allows omitting closing quotes. In addition, all functions are parsed before execution, so adding additional functions below won't help.

The `#` is a *meta*, which has to directly follow an operator. At the start of the function, there is no operator, so it's a syntax error.

The `“` is an opening quote for string literals. It's there because Gaia also allows omitting the opening quote of strings at the start of a function. If this opening quote wasn't here, you could write `#”` which is entirely legal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 6 bytes

```
\""{)
```

(note the leading newline)

The newline prevents line comments, Ly doesn't have block comments, the `\""` ensures that all open string literals will close, and the unmatched brackets raise the error.

Answer (score 0):

## [FRACTRAN](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ffi), 2 bytes

```
()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SytKTC4pSsz7/19D8/9/AA)

Since FRACTRAN doesn't have any way of including comments or literals (AFAICT), this will always error any valid program, since all valid programs must be a valid fraction, and this string can never be part of a valid fraction.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ink](https://inklestudios.com/ink/), 5 bytes

```
*/{}
```

Leading newline ends single-line comments.
`*/` ends multi-line comments. Thanks to the leading newline, you can't put a `/` in front of it to make it the start of a comment rather than the end of one.
`{` and `}` enclose things meant to be parsed, rather than simply printed. If there's nothing between them, the compiler gets sad because it `Expected some kind of logic, conditional or sequence within braces: { ... } but saw '}'`. This happens even inside string literals, so there's no need to check if we're inside one of those.

Answer (score 0):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) 5 bytes

Assuming block editing isn't allowed:

```
0
```

Or with the symbols showing:

```
< cr >< lf >
0
< cr >< lf >
```

Without block editing, it is impossible to stick this behind the comment symbol (';'), as the '0' will end up on the next line anyway. There is no block commenting in Turing Machine Code, a fact that is taken advantage of in other answers here as well. This patch of code would not only not run, it would kill the whole program before it can begin to execute, no matter where it is placed.

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?5d5fd0287196a57a71de4e29163fb358)

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), 2 bytes

Tries to execute an undefined opcode. Milky Way does not have comments. The newline is for ending strings.

```
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83Mya7ULU@s/P@fS/P/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zig 0.6.0](https://ziglang.org), 2 bytes

```
`
```

(`` \n` ``)

A newline will reset the tokenizer state, escaping any comments or multiline strings and erroring for single line strings. Backticks are not a valid character except in strings.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/T9cMx8)

Answer (score 0):

## [KonamiCode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), 3 bytes

`]()`

Explanation:

First, the ] closes any comments this string might be placed in. Then, the () attempts to pass an empty number to the comment closing sign. Using the pynami interpreter, this will always result in an "This command doesn't have a parameter!" error, even if you put it inside a comment.