# Almost Illegal Strings, Mark II (Cops)

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, cops-and-robbers

> Edit 2020-11-06: This challenge has been edited with new provisions to encourage participation. The edits have been **bolded** for emphasis.

Welcome to a cops and robbers version of [Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/find-an-illegal-string).

An *illegal string* is "a string of characters that cannot appear in any legal program in your programming language of choice" (from the linked post).

For this challenge, we will define an *almost illegal string*, which is a string of characters that is very hard, but not impossible, to include in a valid program.

### The Cops' Challenge

- Choose a programming language, and choose an 'almost illegal string' - this is a sequence of characters that is very hard to include in a valid program without causing it to error.
- Write a program that contains the 'almost illegal string' as a contiguous substring that does not error.
- **Optionally, you may also specify a set of banned characters. These are characters that do not appear in your program, except in the 'almost illegal string'. (Therefore: banned characters can still appear inside the almost illegal string)**

That's it! You will reveal the programming language, the almost illegal string, **and the set of banned characters**, and challenge robbers to write a program that contains the illegal string but does not error.

For the purposes of this challenge, we define 'does not error' as:

- Your program exits with exit code 0.
- Your program does not print any output to standard error.
- Your program may print anything to standard output, if you wish, but it does not have to.
- If (and only if) your language *always* prints output to standard error regardless of the program, such as debugging or timing information, you may instead design a program that *only* outputs this to standard error. If you are making use of this clause, mention it in your cop post.

### The Robbers' Challenge

Find an uncracked answer. Write a program in the language specified that contains as a contiguous substring the almost illegal string specified and does not error. **Your program may not use any character in the set of banned characters, unless it is part of the almost illegal string.** Your program does not need to be exactly what the cop had in mind. Post an answer to the robber's thread and leave a comment on the cops' answer to crack it.

### Clarifications

- If your cop answer requires a specific operating environment or version, you must specify this in your answer.
- The cop's almost illegal string that they reveal is to be interpreted with respect to the standard encoding for the language's interpreter. For most programs, this will be UTF8.
- Solutions should not take any input (via standard input, argv, or any other source) and may assume no such input is given.
- Solutions must terminate in a finite amount of time. This means entering an infinite loop and getting killed by TIO's 60 second timeout is not a valid solution.
- Cops should make sure if their almost illegal string contains leading or trailing newlines that it is very clear it does so. Robbers should carefully note any leading or trailing newlines in a cop's post.

### Formatting hint

The clearest way to include leading or trailing newlines is to use the backtick syntax for your post:

````
```

foo

```
````

Renders as:

```
foo
```

To remove any ambiguity, *explicitly mention* the leading/trailing newlines in your post.

### Scoring

After 10 days without a crack, a cop can mark their answer as *safe* and reveal their solution. Once the cop has revealed their solution, it is no longer able to be cracked.

Cops are scored based on the length (in bytes) of their almost illegal string in their safe answer(s), with lower being better.

Robbers are scored by the number of answers they crack, with higher being better.

---

### Example

#### Python 3, 5 bytes

Illegal string:

```
"'1/0
```

Banned characters:

```
#'
```

#### Python 3, cracks example's answer

Program:

```
""" "'1/0 """
```

The idea is that we can just comment out the string, since `"` is not banned.

Comment: It looks too hard to find a suitable language for this. Can I impose some extra [tag:restricted-source] on the robber's code, e.g. banning certain chars, or allowing to add code only after the string, etc?

Comment: @Bubbler I'm not super happy about the idea of editing in extra rules after the challenge, but so be it. If there are no answers in the next 12 hours, I will allow cops to ban the use of a set of characters.

Comment: The number of answers to the original "Find an illegal string" challenge that I flagged for deletion as invalid suggests that this challenge can't possibly be too hard.

Comment: You should probably add the [tag:code-golf] tag to this question because "Cops are scored based on the length (in bytes) of their almost illegal string".

Comment: I added [tag:code-challenge], thinking that [tag:code-golf] doesn't apply since the "illegal strings" aren't code.

Comment: @Bubbler I have edited in new provisions. cops-and-robbers lives and dies with participation, so hopefully this can encourage some answers.

Comment: I don’t really like the fact that the number of banned characters has no impact on the score, as it makes it more open to abuse. However, I do see the problems with trying to incorporate it into the scoring system. Therefore, I’d recommend something like using the number of banned characters as a tie breaker for safe answers of the same length, so it has some impact, but not enough to significantly affect the challenge

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly I definitely see what you mean, on the other hand there isn't a very straightforward way to create a level playing ground in that regard. In some languages, you can ban commenting out by banning one character, in others, you may need to ban multiple. Same for strings etc.

Comment: The scoring system for cops seems strange. If lower is better, and a cop's score is the total length of their safe submissions' illegal strings, then what's the point of posting more submissions after one is safe?

Comment: Here's my idea: have the cops' scores be the total byte count of their safe answers divided by the number of their submissions (i.e. the mean of the lengths of their safe answers).

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 5 bytes ([cracked by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214817/20260))

```python
bin()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PykzT0Pz/38A)

Banned: all characters *except* alphanumeric characters

```python
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

So, you're allowed the above characters and nothing else (in addition to `bin()` itself).

(This idea isn't mine, I remember it from an earlier challenge, but I don't remember who deserves credit for it.)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214817/44718)

Comment: @tsh Yup, you got it!

Comment: @PkmnQ Yes, but why wouldn’t it? “Banned: all characters ***except*** alphanumeric characters”

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oh, I just saw the code block and thought that those were the disallowed characters.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 3 bytes

```
#"
```

(begins with a newline)

Disallowed charachters: `-`

Comment: There are no extra compiler flags, and the file doesn't have to be given a special name right?  I can see ways to solve it with either of these concessions, but it looks very tough otherwise.

Comment: @WheatWizard there is a solution with neither of those, but I'd be intrested in how you'd use those (I made it so it should be fairly difficult even with that). Unless of course you use QuasiQuotes, but what's the fun in that?

Comment: I was thinking of either QuasiQuotes or [cpp](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/3ziGS1lJydaYKzcxM8@2oCgzr0TB@P//f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA "Haskell – Try It Online") neither of which is super fun.  *Even less fun* is to use literate Haskell by naming the file `something.lhs` in which case noncommented lines need to be escaped with `>`, so you can just insert `>main=print 3` and the rest will be a comment.

Comment: Ok and [I cracked it normally](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214868).  Really nice answer.  I didn't even know I could do that!

Comment: @WheatWizard  To be honest, some of that sounds much more interesting than the actual solution.

Comment: @WheatWizard I didn't either, my solution involved strings.

Comment: Feel free to patch it up and post again.  I had fun with this and would be interested in trying a harder version for sure.

Comment: @WheatWizard Haskell is one of the hardest ones to do this with honestly, due to how regular the grammar is.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes, [cracked by HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214815/66833)

```
«{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/5@L69Dq6v//AQ)

You may not use newlines. Any other character/byte is fair game

---

My intended solution was any of the banned characters [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214816/66833) aside from `”`. Each of these characters cause the parsing of the link to break, meaning everything before them gets ignored:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/5@L69Dqao3//wE)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sorry about that, I realised that it could be easily cracked (in a different way to that) and deleted it just as you commented. I've updated my answer so that neither that nor my old crack would work

Comment: Ah, okay no worries. [This](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxwurkOrqx81zP3/HwA) would still be valid then right?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It would, although I'm not quite sure *why*. If you post that as a crack, I'll happily give it to you

Comment: newline and `¶` are the same character and while it's conventional to use `¶` in strings with multiple lines, the Jelly interpreter literally cannot tell the difference because they get mapped to the same codepoint in the SBCS

Comment: I'll keep thinking about this because I do want to try to figure out what you had intended, but in the meantime I will [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214815/68942)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yeah, but `«` is a string terminator, so should close the leading `“`. `{` on a string errors, but for some reason, `”` gets rid of that

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't even realize that. Okay, that's confusing then, lmao

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 7 bytes, [cracked by @EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219334/94066)

Still not the intended answer, so I'm just revealing it. Scroll to the bottom to see it.

```py
raise
```

#### Banned characters

```py
TAB "'(),.=[\]_{|}
```

Non-ASCII characters are all banned as well. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n6soMbM4lev/fwA) or [validate it online](https://tio.run/##tVRta@Q2EP5c/4ppDqpdSHzyi2x5YQ9KLoXQkkBv@6FkQxlJ49jUsYylTW5p@9tT2ZukR1@Ou7T1B9lja56X8YyGvW9snz3Uo72FBl3TtQra28GOHlyDqSii@ZN1z2/3ztNt9EcURWGJnTc0jms7UL9grw3dve53XceOgd2zZTSMbe8X7OJyc7aC8xp80wZAF@4Etu/24Om9B7vzw857Msewt7sR9Ij652lb299h15o4IEWvYL1eA8DJyUlYP/8ZXgWIzQf8d9h2Bn1re2gIg4sYfpzZrSG4sTTRw9FpiI5AUWfv4xniX6uIJoL1yBh7eAjLVbI6Sa7/F3@hdAd/tbX@o/5Q2Tv6r/wN6ByZ9WbcUdTWwLb9iK2jbc@gt35inSSsopAAjw1y@qc/vjqoNJPKKUfb3mNInHy1XUc32IHzIfcmtMaMc@D8Bjs3k2K/X@gnquA/2J4i9gUcbdlieRyvr7bb659@@fU3tvwUJY8CHCjsezKgGwwbQ1Hd3wm4b30Dh5GYezke9o8TAeigPhDW8f3YelpM@MtJ82HCFmyYZxOeMt88TxWkb75KPk3vXHEXygBhOu34D1U6xAe8ScA8@Au19@RmWUHzzteSLZdxQ@9Ne0POL5ZTIa/mnM@8WM0rUeoqlYYyXaalyVPOjZY6SSuZZzWJNEcUiGiyIleJKiUmSV1Skihtioodv4hWSF4kpcnqtMhIEpYc6zoXJRUF8oKjSKogRZCSWmlZV0glSoOoqUhTpfhLaQWvMiGDbixNmadSZkYhFyrDpFBp@EqyEmnJQ6QyQlGmgsqqUlgkRVG9lJZTlqW6rnKOCilPijQvdJVrnuW1VNxURS0wNxpV0INCmUpy5HmFGAouJLIXsF6vnpOe@vL7r0@/hfN3cH6xObt4e/YW3l1@98Pm/PLiy@kYglvcw2Cd/@DEjx@7lEJ3/hXvqc/nLv8oxsPv)!

### Some cracks that work without the banned chars

```py
'''
raise'''
```

```py
"""
raise"""
```

```py
raise SystemExit
```

```py
raiseTABSystemExit # originally posted by EasyasPi here, he found yet another loophole
```

```py
raise\
SystemExit
```

```py
raiser=3 # originally posted by EasyasPi on v1 of this challenge
```

## Intended Answer

> ```py
> #coding:U7
> quit+ACgAKQ-
> raise
> ```

This works because

> the magic comment at the top sets the file encoding to UTF-7

and

> in UTF-7, characters can be encoded by first converting them to their UTF-16 binary representations, and concatenating them if there are multiple characters to be encoded. Here, we want to call `quit`, so we need to convert `()`. This becomes `0000 0000 0010 1000 0000 0000 0010 1001`. Next, we regroup them into groups of 6, to get `000000 000010 100000 000000 001010 01`, and pad the last group with trailing zeros (if necessary). In this case, we get `000000 000010 100000 000000 001010 010000`. Finally, we convert these to the corresponding Base64 characters (table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648)), getting `ACgAKQ`, prepend a `+`, and append a `-`.

So,

> `()` in UTF-7 is `+ACgAKQ-`. We use this fact to bypass the banned `()` and call `quit` anyways, by replacing `()` with `+ACgAKQ-`. This exits the program before it can throw any errors.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219330/94093) again. Your banned characters are like Swiss cheese.

Comment: i don't feel like posting another answer so i'm just going to edit this one if that's fine with you

Comment: @EasyasPi alright i'm about 99% certain i've fixed all loopholes but I'm sure you'll find another one in like 10 seconds xD

Comment: as in I can't see any other loopholes but i'm pretty sure you'll find one anyway

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219334/94093) again. This time I think it is what you had in mind 

Comment: @EasyasPi *sigh* put it through the validator, you'll see it doesn't say it was the intended solution. I like the crack, but it's still not even close to what was intended. I think you might be stuck if I tell you the intended crack works fine if i just append a newline to the illegal string

Comment: The rules do say "Your program does not need to be exactly what the cop had in mind." As for the intended solution, my Python knowledge is pretty bad so I'd probably have better luck brute forcing sha256 

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119911/discussion-between-makonede-and-easyaspi) to prevent extended discussion in comments.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes, [cracked by Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214832/66833)

```
«{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/5@L69Dq6v//AQ)

I'm giving Jelly another go, but with slightly more restrictions. You may not use `quƁƘȤ(ƈɦƙɱɲƥʠʂȥ` (the unimplemented commands in Jelly), `”` or newlines, as these make it *far* too trivial to crack (thanks to [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino) for showing that)

---

Neither HyperNeutrino's crack in the comments, nor Unrelated String's crack was my intended solution. Putting a `Œ` (or any of `ÐÆØœæ`) with nothing after it at the end causes the same behaviour as any of `quƁƘȤ(ƈɦƙɱɲƥʠʂȥ`, as they always expect to have a character after them. Without any character, they cause a break in the program chain, meaning that everything before them is ignored:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/5@L69Dq6qOT/v8HAA)

Comment: I'm really sorry but........ [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/5@L69Dq6keN@/7/BwA). Somehow. Works. (help, jelly is confusing again aah)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Well, at this point Jelly may not be the best language to go for :/ If you post another crack, I‘ll edit it in in the morning

Comment: Yeah... I find that Jelly's quite forgiving on not erroring when you input random things that one wouldn't expect to work. rip :/

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214832/85334) 

Comment: @UnrelatedString Not my intended solution, but very nice!

Comment: Does your intended solution use a similar method, or might it be worth a second repost?

Comment: @UnrelatedString I'm currently editing in my solution, cause I think I've given up on Jelly for this challenge :)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 2 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215202/86301) by Dominic van Essen

```r
'"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X13p/38A)

Banned characters (newlines are banned):

```r
'"`#\qel
```

This bans the obvious cracks I can think of, but I wouldn't be surprised if you come up with a crack very different to what I intend.

[Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) [cracked](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7A0s0RD01pd6f9/AA) a first version of this challenge, and then a [second](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2KDUxxSczL7VYQ8dQk0td6f9/AA); then [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) [cracked](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pz21RCOxoCi/IL9Yo7g0qbikSMNQx0DHQFMz2tDCwDxWU0PTWl3p/38A) a third version. I have added `qel` and newlines to the list of banned character to sidestep their cracks.

---

The solution I had in mind was

```r
assign(intToUtf8(c(37,39,34,37)), c); 1 %'"% 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7G4ODM9TyMzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPYXMfYUsfYRMfYXFNTRyFZ01rBUEFVXUlVwej/fwA)

The assign call creates a new binary operator, `%'"%`; it is equivalent to `"%'"%" <- c`. In R, you can create new operators of the form `%x%` where `x` is *any* string: `%}%`, `%$@%` and `%µ£$%` are all valid operator names. Here, the new operator is equal to the concatenation function `c` and so the output is the vector `1 2`.

Dominic's [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215202/86301) doesn't define the operator; he simply buried it in a `try` call, which is also valid R code.

The trick used here means that any future attempt at an almost illegal string will probably have to ban the `%` character.

Comment: does [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7A0s0RD01pd6f9/AA) count as a crack?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice find! That surely counts, and isn't what I had intended. Since the challenge is very new, I'll edit it to add `q` to the banned characters (rather than posting a new challenge), but feel free to post your crack to the robbers' thread.

Comment: what about [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2KDUxxSczL7VYQ8dQk0td6f9/AA) then?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You're good! I'm now banning new lines as well, hopefully this will do the trick... As a consolation, I will note that your second crack errors when called with `source()`; my intended solution does not. Let's see what you do of the new version!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I [reworked your first crack](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7UsMUejILGoOFWjxDYzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPQ0FjHxEDHxFATCKzVlf7/BwA) -- still not satisfied with that, though.

Comment: There's also a [somewhat shorter version](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pz21RCOxoCi/IL9Yo7g0qbikSMNQx0DHQFMz2tDCwDxWU0PTWl3p/38A)

Comment: Argh! This reminds me of the various iterations that led to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207724/86301). I'll have to add `l` and `e` to the list of illegal characters, to avoid `get`, `ls`, `eval`, `do.call` and the like… (Let me know if you feel I should post this as a separate answer to this thread.)

Comment: Nah, this is fine by me. We'll just start the safety period from the latest version :-)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215202/95126) - and I suspect that this was finally what you had in mind...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Well done! I had a variation on this.

Answer (score 3):

## Desmos, 9 bytes,

```
sort(3,2
```

Banned characters: New Lines

I'm hoping that most people are not familiar with Desmos here, so people wouldn't know what to try.

Note:

An expression in Desmos would be considered an error if it shows a "danger sign" next to the expression, like this:

[image]

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219244/72733)

Comment: [Cracked with a different solution?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220565/90437)

Comment: [I think this is a good crack, using standard Desmos rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220829/96155)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 5 Bytes (Safe)

```
:! =1
```

Banned Characters:

```
|!/"'
```

A nightly compiler is used, you may pass any flags to rustc if you like.

---

[A crack by @EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219254/94093)
does work (and is brilliant), but I think because the question says "you must write a program that contains ...", if your code is not designed to run, it isn't a program :)

### The intended solution

The idea is to create a local variable that has the never type, call some functions on the integer 1 such that it becomes the never type.

However, with `!` as a banned character, we can't simply put the `#![feature(never_type)]` attribute on the top of the program. We must use an unstable rustc flag that allows us to inject crate-level attributes. The command to compile would be:

```
cargo rustc -- -Z crate-attr='feature(never_type, core_panic)'
```

Because closures (`|| something`) and the use of the `!` type outside are restricted, we must operate on the integer literal with provided functions. This is where the `core_panic` feature comes in and gives us a nice way to transform a `&str` into `!`. We know the start and the end, we can just put them together:

```rust
use std::io::stdout;
use core::panicking::panic_str;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    let a:! =1i8.checked_neg().as_ref().map(ToString::to_string).as_ref().map(Borrow::borrow).map(panic_str).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219254/94093) possibly

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 10 bytes, [cracked by The Fifth Marshal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220920/46076)

```py
?"""?'''?
```

### Banned characters

Alphanumeric, whitespace, and non-ASCII.

---

> The intended solution makes use of an interesting quirk in the Python parser.

Here's a hint if you want one:

> The hint is that there is no hint. (This isn't a joke. This is actually the hint.)

---

## Intended Answer

> Hexdump:
>
> ```
> 00000000: 2300 0a3f 2222 223f 2727 273f  #..?"""?'''?
> ```

For some reason,

> the Python parser seems to ignore characters following null characters.

So,

> it ignores the newline after the `#␀`, therefore treating the `?"""?'''?` as part of the comment.

Fun fact: This was actually posted on the original Find an Illegal String challenge, but when I found a way to get around it, I decided to post it here.

Comment: Oops lol... shouldn't have let that happen. Try with question marks there instead this time. Lol

Comment: Dw, I'll try to look for your intended solution :)

Comment: Are you referring to type hints here?

Comment: Possibly. For now though, all that's written in the answer is all you'll get.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220920/46076)

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI The fact that there's "no" hint refers to the null byte in the code ("null" means nothing; as in, the absence of anything).

Comment: Ah, I see now. (filler)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 4 bytes, cracked by [tail spark rabbit ear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231255/100411)

```
<Esc><Esc>ZQ
```

This one is a bit more difficult than my other Vim one.

#### Intended Solution:

> `i<C-o>:<C-r><Esc><Esc>ZQ`

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231255/100411)

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear Nice, I forgot that windows were a thing. The intended solution was very different, but I like yours, too.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 5 bytes, [Cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214877/92901)

```
?""":
```

Disallowed charachters: `#`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214877/92901)

Comment: @Dingus That's a pretty simple solution, don't know how I missed it. I made a more difficult version that should require the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 17 bytes, [cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214869/92901)

```
=end
#{"""'}
=end
```

(no newline at start)

Disallowed charachters: `N`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214869/92901)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 6 bytes

```
?""":
```

There is a zero width space before the `:`

Disallowed characters: `#`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215095/92901)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 13 bytes, [Cracked by EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218679/94093)

```python
int(А,В,С)
```

Banned Characters: All ascii characters except `2()~+` and newlines. `'"#=` are banned.

```python
 !"#$%&'*,-./013456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
```

The solution makes use of an odd python 3 feature.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvROPCBJ0Lk3QuLNT8/x8A)

Comment: [ℭ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218679/94093)

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty . lol.

Answer (score 2):

## nasm, 4 bytes, safe

```
[al]
```

Banned characters:

```
;"`'%#
```

### Solution:

> `section` is, as far as I know, the only thing in NASM which accepts an arbitrary string without quotes.
>
> ```
>         section [al]
>         section .text
>         global _start
> _start:
>         mov     eax, 60
>         syscall
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywuTs1NyqnUzUsszv3/XwEKilOTSzLz8xSiE3NiudAF9UpSK0rgouk5@UmJOQrxxSWJRSVcEMoKLpubXwamUxMrdBTMDBBmVRYnJ@bkKPz/DwA)

Stop giving me these assembly ones for free.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3 bytes, [Cracked by user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219498/95792)

I can't believe I missed that obvious loophole! I am adding a slightly revised version of my code that should avoid this.

### New Answer, 4 bytes, [Cracked by Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219508/85334)

```python
 1=2
```

Note: There is a `space` at the beginning of the code.

Banned characters: All non-ascii characters, quotes, and #.

```python
"'#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X8HQ1uj/fwA)

### Old Answer, 3 bytes, [Cracked by user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219498/95792):

```python
1=2
```

Banned characters: All non-ascii characters, quotes, and #.

```python
"'#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39DW6P9/AA)

#### My intended solution for both posts:

```python
foo : 1=2
```

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219498/95792)

Comment: LOL! That was fast. :)

Comment: The new link and byte count don't match the text ` 1+1=2`.

Comment: ...[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219508/85334)

Comment: I'll fix the link. Thx. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 7 bytes, [cracked by Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220576/16484)

```js
...void
```

## Javascript, 8 bytes, [cracked by Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220578/16484)

Note one trailing space

```js
...void
```

Banned characters:

- all comments: `//`, `/**/`
- all strings: `""`, ``` `` ```, `''`
- curlies: `{}`
- brackets: `[]`
- asterisk: `*`
- the letter `w`

Clarifications: My cop answer works in a browser environment, but there are probably solutions in Node too.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220576/94066)

Comment: @Makonede Thanks for the effort, looks like I overlooked the easiest approach of all. If you're interested, I added an updated version of the challenge that should be a bit more interesting.

Comment: [still too simple...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220578/94066)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```ruby
=end
#{"""'}
=end
```

Disallowed characters: `N`,`%`

This time I made it a bit harder.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214869/92901), though not sure it's what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 18 bytes

```
=end
#{/"""'}
=end
```

Disallowed characters: `N`,`%`,`/`

my final variation, hopefully the next solution is the intended one.

Comment: The approach used in my [second crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214869/92901) also works for this version. Is there supposed to be another disallowed character?

Comment: @Dingus I guess there is now. I thought the `/` would stop the regex approach, but I should have checked.

Comment: And just to clarify, the almost illegal string is the same as before - `/` is not part of it any more? (Asking because the header still says 18 bytes.)

Comment: @Dingus It's supposed to be there, not sure what happened to it. I probably don't need it but I'd hate for not including it to be the reason another solution slips past.

Comment: Is [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/38YmmEu5Wr2WyzY1LwXI0ldSUoLxgv//BwA "Ruby – Try It Online") the solution you had in mind?

Comment: @Dingus almost. My version used unintrpolated docstrings, but that works too. If only I put the `/` on the other side...

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh

```
 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream> 
 
int main() { 
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    hello(); 
    return rand() % 2; 
} 
 
/* 
  main 
  a=0 
  \ 
  print "$((1/$a))" 
*/ 
 
void hello() std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
```

- Allowed characters: all printable ASCII *except* `` blxy<'`$ `` (lowercase B, L, X, and Y, single-quote, grave, dollar sign)
- Please note all the leading and trailing whitespace.

Probably not too hard but you may learn a lot about the many - shall we say "quirks" - of zsh.

Comment: Pretty sure [this](https://tio.run/##TY5NC8IwDIbv@RWxTmiHMPW4r7OH4U28eKlrYYWulbbzoPjbZzsUDCQhzxve5OmHeebNvup5wLqWsFam15OQWPc@CK1u7R9S1gcn@dgCKBNw5MpQhi/AGN5xI2hQo6Snc9cxVi14kFpb@h2cDJMzuGwy3OChgjdAkUcxecXGm12s15h3l06QjNJ9kXHGCOQFwMMq8fPE@GBZ9nZKnyM5JrrFi3VarEhCiy6N0BXIef4A "Zsh – Try It Online") is not what you had in mind?

Comment: @xigoi no, I forgot to disallow `<` oops

Comment: [Even simpler exploit](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwDIbveYpYJ7RDmHrc5s4ehjfx4qWuhRW6VrpORPHZazsUDCQh3x/@5Dn2IciH8rBUptOTkFh3oxdaXZs/pOzoneRDA6CMx4ErQxm@AGOMjhtBvRokPZ7alrFqxr3U2tLv4KSfnMF5k@EKdxW8AYo8iskrNr7fxHqJeXPpBMko3RYZZ4xAXgDcrRI/T4wPlmVnJ491jeSQ6BrP1mmxIAnNujRCVyF8AA), which probably can't be avoided unfortunately.

Comment: @xigoi Clearly I didn't think carefully enough about this

Comment: [still too simple](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwDIbveYpYJ7RDmHrc5s4ehjfx4qWuhRW6VrrOg@Kz13YqGEhCvoT/z2PsQ3DST87AUplOT0Ji3Y1eaHVt/pCyo3eSDw2AMh4Hrgxl@ASMMTpuBPVqkPR4alvGqhn3UmtLv8PHA@dLhivcVfACKPK4TFqx8f0m1kvMm0sWJKN0W2ScMQJ5AXC3Svw0MT5Ylp2dPNY1kkOiazxbp8WCJDTvpRG6CuEN "Zsh – Try It Online"), do you need to ban another character? :P

Comment: @Cinaski it's been so long I can't remember what the actual solution was and what character I would need to ban (it's even possible that *was* my intended solution) Also looking at this now I can think of at least 4 more solutions lol

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229556/100411)

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, 2 bytes, [cracked by PkmnQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214959/96039)

Substring:

```
\
```

(Note the newline in the beginning)

Banned characters: All alphanumeric characters

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

I'm hoping that most people are not familiar with Desmos here, so people wouldn't know what to try.

Note:

An expression in Desmos would be considered an error if it shows a "danger sign" next to the expression, like this:

[image]

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214706/almost-illegal-strings-mark-ii-robbers/214959#214959)

Comment: @PkmnQ You got it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 6 bytes, [cracked by EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219328/94093)

[@EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94093/easyaspi)'s crack does work (and I'm dumb for letting it work), but I'm not revealing the original solution yet; I've posted a v2 hopefully preventing any loopholes.

```
raise
```

#### Banned characters

```
 "'(),.:[\]_{|}
```

Non-ASCII characters are all banned as well. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n6soMbM49f9/AA) or [validate it online](https://tio.run/##tVTrb5swEP/OX3FrpRmkhPJyXlIqTV0nRZtSac0@TG01GfsIaAQj7CRF2/72zEDSVXtUbbfxwXDg@z3ufJS1TmUR7pJKriBlKs2zGLJVKSsNKmUBHVjtJ6nu3tZK48r6EVmWWVylBVbVVJZY2ORE4OakWOc56QHZEscqq6zQNplfLM4nMEtAp5kBVOaOIIu8Bo23GuRal2utUfSglusKeMX452ZbVmxYngnXIFnHMJ1OAaDf75v16c9wbCAW9/g3LMsF05ksIEVmXLjwsWWXAmEpsaGHozMTHUGMudy6LcRfq7AagmlFCNntzHLlT/r@zX/xZ0rX@Uuk1A/6Y7Hc4L/yVzKlUEwX1RqtLAFyXVQsU0igkLrhbARMLLMd9sfj7Kd@TzqNotHY5HBZaGYSG1dZnuOS5aC0yV2ag9HidIxvWK5aSlbUNj9QGffGdBMROLomttNzJ1fXN5@@fP1GnMfo2NMriFlRoACeMrPRFFT9jn6b6RS6cWjPsVvW@2kApiDpCBN3W2Ua7QbfaRR302WTsp1LOGSe3k0UBKcv/cfpbautTBHATKas/lCjLu7wGgHt0NtxrVG1sozmtU5GxHHcFG9FtkSlbacp41Wb88SL@CM6pMIfYOj7PGYR514Yc98LR8Mxw4iOByIc@CEVGKM39GKMGY0i7kWcMk/QgPSeReshHQ7ZOBhEvkcTpD43AoIw4UPuDaJgHFMxSMbDEHkSBJx6PKFxIrwg9HwuRpSTZ7DeTO6SDp16/@rsLcwuYTZfnM9fn7@Gy4t3Hxazi/mLZihhxWoopdL3/n/uvm9o@vUr3qHzbd8fxNh9Bw)!

### Some cracks that work without the banned chars

```
'''
raise'''
```

```
"""
raise"""
```

```
raise SystemExit
```

```
raise\
SystemExit
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219328/94093). EZ.

Comment: Oof ok. Posting a v2. lol

Comment: @EasyasPi try now, hopefully i've fixed that loophole

Comment: the intended answer is quite sneaky if i do say so myself, even more so than [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218612/94066), [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214813/94066), and even [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218525/94066).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 3 bytes, cracked by [tail spark rabbit ear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231255/100411)

```
<Esc>ZQ
```

A Vim program doesn't really "error out" per se, but `ZQ` will exit the current file without saving, so it can't be executed in a valid program, thereby making it "illegal".

This is a bit of an easier one, if you know Vim.

#### Intended Solution:

> `i<C-v><Esc>ZQ`

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231255/100411)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231514/100664)

```
«Wi«»Wi»`Wi`Wi
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%0A%C2%ABWi%C2%AB%C2%BBWi%C2%BB%60Wi%60Wi&inputs=&header=&footer=)

No bans, do what you want. Note that silently erroring at compile-time (Nothing appears in the 'output' box) counts as an error - even the empty program outputs 0...

My intended solution was prepending a `[` to just make sure the code isn't run.

Comment: You should make a round 2 because this is [crack'd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231514/78850)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (THREE.js 105) (Must include canvas element) ~48 bytes

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(cube);
```

*Note empty lines*
[Try it!](https://jsfiddle.net/jh6x5tpa/)

Banned Characters: All quote characters

`/`

Comment: @Davide, look at the banned characters

Comment: Omg I am sorry, I've misunderstood the role of banned characters.

Comment: why not just prepend `cube = new THREE.Object3D();`? (I've never used three.js before, I took the class name from the error message)

Comment: The way to create a new cube is much more complex due to the fact that it uses webgl to display 3d graphics @thedefault.

Comment: @HitchHacker I don't have to create a cube. When I prepend `cube = new THREE.Object3D();`, the program runs without errors.

Comment: Oh i guess it does

Comment: What do you mean Must include canvas? Do I have to genuinely use Three.js?

Comment: This is now safe.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 32 bytes

```
X$globals()$"imp_print"$mod$

""
```

Banned characters are:

```
$\LMN."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0IlPSc/KTGnWENTRSkztyC@oCgzr0RJJTc/RYWLS0np//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 7 bytes

```python
"""'''$
```

(Note no starting or trailing newline.)

Disallowed characters:

```
#
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but if there's no leading newline, couldn't you just comment this out?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X0lJSV1dXQVI/f8PAA)