# Almost Illegal Strings, Mark II (Robbers)

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, cops-and-robbers

This is the robbers' thread for 'Almost Illegal Strings'.

See the [cop's thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/214705/48931) for information on participating. A section from the post is included here for convenience.

> ### The Robbers' Challenge
>
> Find an uncracked answer. Write a program in the language specified that contains as a contiguous substring the almost illegal string specified and does not error. Your program may not use any character in the set of banned characters, unless it is part of the almost illegal string. Your program does not need to be exactly what the cop had in mind. Post an answer to the robber's thread and leave a comment on the cops' answer to crack it.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 7 bytes, cracks [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214813/44718)

```python
0xbin()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/36AiKTNPQ/P/fwA)

The answer is easy to understand if syntax highlighting for above snippet works correctly.

So bad. The syntax highlighting *did* work correctly. But SO changed their render library... Anyway, above code is:

```python
0xb in ()
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting *is* working correctly :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), [doge doge's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214865/56656), 26 bytes

```hs
main=print()where{3
#""=3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0RDszwjtSi12phLWUnJ1rj2/38A)

The idea here is that within a `{}` block whitespace rules are weakened a good deal. With that we can turn `#"` into the declaration of an infix function and write the rest of our program with no issues.  From there we use `where` attached to our `main` function to start the block.

I don't really know why these blocks have weaker rules.  I am just learning about this now as well.  But for some reason I had a suspicion it might work and it does.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), cracks [Robin Ryder's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215086/95126)

```r
try(x %'"% y,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6SoUqNCQVVdSVWhUidE8/9/AA)

The 'almost illegal' string we're trying to use is `'"`.

`try` attempts to run the code contained in its first argument.  The second argument, `silent` (not explicitly named here) is set to `T`RUE to prevent output if the result is an error.

The first argument here attempts to apply the (nonexistant) `%'"%` function to (nonexistant) variables `x` and `y`.
The `%...%` notation - known as SPECIAL in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) - allows us to incorporate characters that are usually forbidden for variables and function names, like `'"` in this case.

Comment: Very nice; I had looked at `%'"%` before (remembering the original illegal string challenge) but didn't `try` it :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes, cracks [caird coinheringaahing's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214814/68942)

```
“

«{”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxwurkOrqx81zP3/HwA)

**EDIT**

I actually don't know why this works lmao

Comment: Looking back, I think this might be closer to the intended solution than we thought--`”` or `⁾` at the end of the program [can't parse](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/70c9fd93ab009c05dc396f8cc091f72b212fb188/jelly/interpreter.py#L3141) as a single or double character literal, so it's basically the same as `Œ`!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes, cracks [caird coinheringaahing's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214816/85334)

```
«{0¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/5@L69DqaoNDC///BwA)

Instead of string literal weirdness, this uses the fact that arity mismatches don't cause errors until things are actually evaluated--`{` doesn't try to turn a monad into a dyad so much as it calls a Python lambda assumed to have one argument from a Python lambda with two arguments, and `0¡` repeats it zero times.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [qwatry's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218612/94093)

Illegal text: `int(A,B,C)`, with all ASCII but `~+2()` and newlines banned.

```python
((22+22+22+~2+2)+(22+22+22+~2+2+~2+~2+2)+(22+22+22)+(22+22+22+~2+2+~2+~2+2)+(22+22+22+2+2+~2)+(22+22+22+~2+2+~2+~2+2)+(22+22+2+2))
int(A,B,C)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7//8PcKYuAeCuUXqABIoB4KRCv1zAy0oagOiCpqY1bDkTgUUOBVm2IEvJNAIprcgEF1oIEM/NKNBx1nHScNf//BwA)

Python 3 normalizes Unicode identifiers, so " " is turned into "fancy unicode".

This turns it into

```python
exec(chr(22+22+22+~2+2)+chr(22+22+22+~2+2+~2+~2+2)+chr(22+22+22)+chr(22+22+22+~2+2+~2+~2+2)+chr(22+22+22+2+2+~2)+chr(22+22+22+~2+2+~2+~2+2)+chr(22+22+2+2))
print(A,B,C)
```

And when we expand the `chr` statements, we get `'A=B=C=0'`:

```python
exec('A=B=C=0')
print(A,B,C)
```

And you can figure it out from there.

I would love to say I discovered it, but nah. This isn't the first time normalization memes have been posted here.

Also, I brute forced the ASCII arithmetic instead of calculating it, so it is not optimized.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes, cracks [@binarycat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214924/92901)

```julia
`\?""":"`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PyHGXklJ6V1Ht5VSwv//AA)

Backticks in Julia delimit shell commands, as in Perl or Ruby. But unlike Perl or Ruby, the command isn't actually executed; rather, a `Cmd` object representing the command is created. Hence it doesn't matter that `\?""":"` isn't a valid shell command.

Comment: Nice! This is actually really close to my intended solution, which was to write a custom command macro, but apparently you can just put a backslash in front, probably should have tried that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes, cracks @dogedoge's [first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214867/92901)

```ruby
%q(=end
#{"""'}
=end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X7VQwzY1L4VLuVpJSUm9lgvE0fz/HwA)

Wraps the almost illegal string in a single-quoted string (which doesn't allow interpolation).

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes, cracks @dogedoge's [first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214867/92901) and [second](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214870/92901) answers

```ruby
/#{'}=end
#{"""'}
=end/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X1@5Wr3WNjUvhUu5WklJSb2WC8TR//8fAA)

Here's an alternative that doesn't use `%` (in response to a comment). This time we wrap in a regexp, interpolating a single quote to close the `"""'` sequence that occurs later.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 28 bytes, cracks @dogedoge's [third answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214873/92901)

```ruby
<<S
#{'}=end
#{/"""'}
=end
S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/38YmmEu5Wr3WNjUvBcjQV1JSUq/lAvOC//8HAA)

Now the wrapper is a here doc. This approach also works for the first two cops (which don't include the `/`).

Comment: Nice! but can you do it without `%`?

Comment: @dogedoge Yep :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes, cracks [@dogedoge's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214866/92901)

```julia
"""?"""::Any
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X0lJyR6Irawc8yr//wcA)

Define a (triple-quoted) string and assert it to be of type `Any` (`String` also works).

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, 5 bytes, cracks [Aiden Chow's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214955/91569)

```
\{\}
```

Comment: Yes the second one is the intended answer.

Comment: The first one uses alphanumeric characters so it's not a valid answer.

Comment: @AidenChow Ok, I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

## Rust `-Z unstable-options --pretty normal`, cracks [@Deadbeef's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218719/94093)

```rust
const x:! =1;
```

Not sure if this is the intended interpretation of "you may pass any flags to rustc if you like." or a loophole.

I could just do `--help` but this one actually parses the file and needs a *sorta* valid Rust program.

Specifically, the `--pretty` option on Nightly will just format the code instead of compiling it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [qwatry's revised answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219496/85334)

```python
x: 1=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8JKwdDW6P9/AA)

or

```python
x: 1+1=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8JKwVDb0Nbo/38A)

(not entirely sure which it's supposed to be but it works either way).

I completely forgot how *flexible* type hints are until I <s>cheated</s> searched [the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for the `=` character.

Comment: Yep, that's the essentially solution the solution I had!

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, to crack [HitchHacker's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218525/72733) cop

There is in fact a way to crack this answer without using notes. Type the closing parenthesis `)` after the expression, then go back one character and type the closing bracket `]`. The result, `sort(3,2])`, should be interpreted as `sort([3,2])`.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this technically works under [Desmos rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com), cracks [Etheryte's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220563/94066)

```js
void$=Array();console.log(...void$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/LD8zRcXWsagosVJD0zo5P684PydVLyc/XUNPTw8sqfn/PwA)

This seems way too easy... Uses spread syntax `...expression` to use the elements of `void$` (initialized to `Array()`, an empty array `[]`) as separate arguments to `console.log`. Since it's empty, it uses no arguments, which is perfectly valid as well; it just calls `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com), cracks [Etheryte's revised answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220563/94066)

```js
eval(...void 0||Array())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f/fsagosVJDT0@vLD8zRcGgpgYioKn5/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, cracks [HitchHacker's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218525/96155)

```
\sort(3,2
```

Desmos programs are normally [scored](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations) based on the text pasted into the textbox. Pasting in invalid-formatted text simply does nothing, which doesn't meet the error criteria of showing a "danger sign" laid out by HitchHacker. The easiest way to do this is by using a `\` before sort. Desmos doesn't recognize "sort" as an escapable sequence like `\left` or `\operatorname` or even `\sin` so it simply ignores the whole program.

Comment: I wonder if there is another copy-pasteable solution that doesn't silently error? Currently looking for one.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, cracks [Makonede's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220511/46076)

Code contains unprintable characters, so is provided as a hexdump:

```
00000000: 2300 0400 040a 3f22 2222 3f27 2727 3f    #.....?"""?'''?
```

Derived from [feersum's comment on an identical Python answer to the original find an illegal string challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/find-an-illegal-string#comment331528_133489). I made it slightly shorter and adjusted it to the banned characters in this challenge, but have no idea how or why this works.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/n6uiIkVBt0hBLzOvoLREryQzX6FGoaCyJCM/z/j/fwMosFIwMjYwUDAwgRCJCsZpRkYKRkAAYpkrGJkDCeM0BSBQ1gMBeyUlJXt1dXV7AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, cracks [HitchHacker answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218525/72733)

The solution is in the answer, **note** is the key: instead of evaluating it as an expression the *illegal string* is put in a note ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[image]

Comment: Technically, the answer would be `"sort(3,2`.

Comment: Dang it i just came up with this then found ur answer lol

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [Makonede's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219280/94093)

```python
raiser=3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n6soMbM4tcgWyAQA)

Should've banned `=`...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [Makonede's second challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219329/94093)

```python
raiseTABSystemExit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n6soMbM4lTO4srgkNde1IrPk/38A)

I am sure this is another unintended loophole…

Comment: *sigh...* this sucks

Comment: oops deny that edit please i didn't know SE converts tabs to spaces lol

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [Makonede's revised second challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219329/94093)

```python
raiser:str
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n6soMbM4tciquKTo/38A)

Uses a type annotation. I think this is the actual solution you meant.

Comment: Nope. Not quite.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), cracks [qwatry's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219496/95792)

```python
foo1=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py0/39DW6P9/AA)

The string to crack is `1=2`.

Comment: Not exactly the intended solution. Can't believe I missed this... I'll probably edit my answer a bit to avoid this loophole. LOL

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), cracks [pxeger's post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214882/100411), cracked after being safe.

Did I get the rules correctly?

```sh
a=1;: " 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream> 
 
int main() { 
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    hello(); 
    return rand() % 2; 
} 
 
/* 
  main 
  a=0 
  \ 
  print "$((1/$a))" 
*/ 
 
void hello() std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; 
 "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NC8IwDIbv/opYJ7RDmPO4D88ehjfx4qWuhRW6VtrOg@Jvr81kYA4JeZK8eV9@iJG3ZV0BgdVGmV5PQkLT@yC0uh//mbI@OMnHBGGlTICRK0MZvFOfwjtuBA1qlPR86TrG6h8fpNaWLp2TYXIG5l0GWzgk/kHBIscFlMTK2z2WG6aHw2cko7QsMs5YMpoXePK0SizykAxXVW@nAE0D5IR0B1frtFgTRPNcGqHRCInxCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 6 bytes, cracks [Aaron Miller's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231057/100411)

```
<C-w>n<Esc><Esc>ZQ
```

### What it does

- Make a new window first.
- Close it by last four keys.

---

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 5 bytes, cracks [Aaron Miller's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231056/100411)

```
<C-w>n<Esc>ZQ
```

Same as above.

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal, 16 bytes, Cracks [A Username's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231511/78850)

```
Q
«Wi«»Wi»`Wi`Wi
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=Q%0A%C2%ABWi%C2%AB%C2%BBWi%C2%BB%60Wi%60Wi&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Ez. Just quit before you get to the unavoidable stuff.