# Program compressor

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, compression

Choose a language and write a program in the language that:

- Take a valid program of the language as input,
- Output a string(bytearray, etc.). It needn't be a valid program.
- Only finite valid inputs result in longer/same-length(in bytes) output.
- Different valid input, even if behave same, lead to different output.

Let length of your code as \$L\$ and number of inputs with longer/equal-length output as \$n\$. To win, you should be lowest on at least one of:

- \$L\$,
- \$N\$,
- \$L+N\$,
- \$L+\log_2(N+1)\$.

## Notes

- Solution exist so long as [illegal substring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/) exist.

Comment: Please make the objective and rules of the challenge clearer.

Comment: @Binary198 Please make your request clearer :)

Comment: Well, what is the program intended to do exactly, and how does the scoring system work?

Comment: @Binary198 To compress all programs but finite ones. Some users would make four questions for four scoring way but it likely make a mess

Comment: So, you need to take a program as input and output a unique string that will be longer than or equal to in length than the input? Still, the scoring system is weird. What is \$N\$, and why are there multiple scoring ways? I would usually just go with one.

Comment: @Binary198 It should usually be shorter, but since for lots of languages empty or one letter is valid program, it's impossible to shorten them more. Therefore we need to allow finite exceptions, and the amount is \$N\$

Comment: But what is \$N\$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133344/discussion-between-l4m2-and-binary198).

Comment: @l4m2 I have an edit prepared with a goal of making it a little easier to read and understand while not affecting your challenge specification (hopefully!), are you OK to review it (rolling back / amending if necessary)? If not I'll hold off...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), \$L=79\$, \$N\approx255^{1500}\$

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allan</sup>

```python
f=lambda b,s=0,l=0:b and f(b[1:],255*s+b[0],l+1)or s.to_bytes(l-(l>1500),"big")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBDoIwFET3nqLWBS1UQzEkhgTX3sAFIYZK0SaflrR1wemxagwx6l/Nnzczw@ivRm93g506a3rkRodUPxjrkZPeyvPNOmU0qF75xZdDeBqOTl0JTS/aBgnmypRBmRYCNbpFHREVL2qW5XnsElGlNYOEU2OR23hzEqOXjsCawJ7nYYhhoS6YToNV2pNQxpjSxfy9VHSQAAYdjYV2GdFHZDVnGhw/t949kPrT/w34P5AFMN0B)

Python source code can't contain null bytes. This converts the input (bytestring) to base 255 and then back to bytes. After 1500 removes a redundant byte.

Comment: Do you save one byte iff length>1500?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, exactly

Comment: You don't need the `f=` (I guess you were going to go with a recursive function which would need it, and left it in).

Comment: Using recursion (which I _think_ we may assume to have no limit set for code-golf purposes), you could do `f=lambda b,s=0,l=0:b and f(b[1:],255*s+b[0],l+(l!=1500))or s.to_bytes(l,"big")` for \$L=78\$ [TIO](https://tio.run/##bYxdC4IwFIbv/RVzXbjpCC2EELzvH3QhEi5nDc4@2NaFv94WBhL1Xp334zl2Dg@jjyfrlskZhfzskVTWuIC8CE7cns5Lo0EqGZKfhFRlFF2mFgbFxwFx5tuSQVs2HA16RBPhXdX07FDXuS94V/YMCgJpW9WRo8Yhvw/myucgPAGGubxjulgndSCRxZjSZHPrlZ0FgEEX42BMM/qe7LbNgPP194cDob/z/0UVi@UF)

Comment: Hmm, maybe not - I don't understand [this error](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDoIwFAXXcoovG1qohqokSIIXIcS0UrDJpyVtXRDC2RHXznKSeW@aw9uaazm5rXd2BD970ONkXQCvglOvj/PaGtSjDtGfITz/Qbe@RjHKToBkvs4Z1nklQZgOeiIbXrXsUhSpz2STtwwzgseaF3tHrQN/DvYp56A8QRZLPcT73O4RtAEnzKAIv91LBrzgnFbRYXLaBNInC65wesCCypD9JhZxipSuCd2@)

Comment: @JonathanAllan fixed it. Your code didn't increment `l` past 1500

Comment: Haha, oh yeah! (It was a bad attempt at golfing what you now have.)